# Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I would like to put a Git project on GitHub but it contains certain files with sensitive data (usernames and passwords, like /config/deploy.rb for capistrano).

I know I can add these filenames to **.gitignore**, but this would not remove their history within Git.

I also don't want to start over again by deleting the /.git directory.

Is there a way to remove **all** traces of a particular file in your Git history?

Comment: Related: [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-do-i-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-in-git-history) and [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-unwanted-file-from-git-repository-history).

Comment: related https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 612, accepted):

For all practical purposes, the *first* thing you should be worried about is **CHANGING YOUR PASSWORDS!** It's not clear from your question whether your git repository is entirely local or whether you have a remote repository elsewhere yet; if it is remote and not secured from others you have a problem. If anyone has cloned that repository before you fix this, they'll have a copy of your passwords on their local machine, and there's no way you can force them to update to your "fixed" version with it gone from history. The only safe thing you can do is change your password to something else everywhere you've used it.

---

With that out of the way, here's how to fix it. [GitHub answered exactly that question as an FAQ](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data):

**Note for Windows users**: use double quotes (") instead of singles in this command

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'git update-index --remove PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA' <introduction-revision-sha1>..HEAD
git push --force --verbose --dry-run
git push --force
```

**Update 2019:**

This is the current code from the FAQ:

```
  git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
  git push --force --verbose --dry-run
  git push --force
```

Keep in mind that once you've pushed this code to a remote repository like GitHub and others have cloned that remote repository, you're now in a situation where you're rewriting history. When others try pull down your latest changes after this, they'll get a message indicating that the changes can't be applied because it's not a fast-forward.

To fix this, they'll have to either delete their existing repository and re-clone it, or follow the instructions under "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" in the [git-rebase manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

**Tip**: Execute `git rebase --interactive`

---

In the future, if you accidentally commit some changes with sensitive information but you notice **before** pushing to a remote repository, there are some easier fixes. If you last commit is the one to add the sensitive information, you can simply remove the sensitive information, then run:

```
git commit -a --amend
```

That will amend the previous commit with any new changes you've made, including entire file removals done with a `git rm`. If the changes are further back in history but still not pushed to a remote repository, you can do an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

That opens an editor with the commits you've made since your last common ancestor with the remote repository. Change "pick" to "edit" on any lines representing a commit with sensitive information, and save and quit. Git will walk through the changes, and leave you at a spot where you can:

```
$EDITOR file-to-fix
git commit -a --amend
git rebase --continue
```

For each change with sensitive information. Eventually, you'll end up back on your branch, and you can safely push the new changes.

Comment: [git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --remove filename' <introduction-revision-sha1>..HEAD] running this didn't rewrite the commit history, on running 'git log' still commit history is present. is there any spl thing to check ?

Comment: Just for the record: The github link does work, but I had to write the path of the file. I.e: src/path/to/file.extension

Comment: Got this to work. I was lost in translations.  I used the link instead of the command here. Also, Windows command ended up requiring double-quotes as ripper234 mentions, full path as MigDus suggests, and not including the "\" characters that the link pasted as new line wrapping indicators.  Final command looked something like: git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch src\[Project]\[File].[ext]" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

Comment: There seem to be some substantive differences between your `filter-branch` code and that in the github page you linked to.  E.g their 3rd line `--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`.  Has the solution changed or am I missing something?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the github provided solution (which is different) did.

Comment: For anyone using this.. for me 'introduction sha' means the commit BEFORE the file existed. if I provided the SHA of the commit the file was created in it didn't work.

Comment: Note that afterwards, you should `rm .git/refs/original/heads/[BRANCHNAME]` and `git gc --prune=all --aggressive` to get rid of leftovers from the filtering. But be aware of the consequences of using `--prune=all`, namely "Unless the repository is quiescent, you will lose newly created objects that haven’t been anchored with the refs and end up corrupting your repository"

Comment: This solution looks quite good, but if I've introduced the file to remove in the initial commit `<introduction-revision-sha1>..HEAD` doesn't work. It only removes the file from the second commit onward. (How do I include the initial commit into the range of commits?) The save way is pointed out here: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/
`git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Comment: I got an `ambiguous argument` error in Github Desktop on Windows, turns out there were invisible characters when pasting the sha1 copied from Github Desktop

Comment: This doesn't work in windows even with the double quotes. What's the ..HEAD about, doesn't seem valid

Comment: Thank you for this. I finally able to get rid of my poor practice many years ago for a personal repository.

Comment: this command does not remove files in all branches, nor tags. [Official github help](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) works perfectly

Comment: This answer, as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741586/8075923) are both of great value for the community. Thanks guys, +1.

Comment: You don't have to use double quotes on Windows if you use Git Bash instead of Git Cmd

Comment: I get `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: For me it work without backslashes on macOS. Reference this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137662/6753606

Comment: DESTROYED my local repo!

Comment: Hi, could you please add the fact that one should also check with the support of the relevant host? Cleaning the git repo is not enough, you need to reach out to the repository host for further cleaning on their own servers. You also need to make the repositiory private as soon as possible if that's an option, it should be the first thing to do. This is not stressed enough in this answser imo.

Comment: THIS DELETES THE FILE OFF THE OS FILE SYSTEM!!! `git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` and the path is the RELATIVE path w/respect to the git directory, with no leading slash

Comment: Did not work for me. File still existed in one of the earlier commits.

Answer (score 141):

Changing your passwords is a good idea, but for the process of removing password's from your repo's history, I recommend the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a faster, simpler alternative to `git-filter-branch` explicitly designed for removing private data from Git repos.

Create a `private.txt` file listing the passwords, etc, that you want to remove (one entry per line) and then run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text private.txt  my-repo.git
```

All files under a threshold size (1MB by default) in your repo's history will be scanned, and any matching string (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be replaced with the string "***REMOVED***". You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is typically 10-50x faster than running `git-filter-branch` and the options are simplified and tailored around these two common use-cases:

- Removing **Crazy Big Files**
- Removing **Passwords, Credentials** & other **Private data**

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: This is an option, but it could break your application when the passwords are used, e.g. to set up a database connection. I'd prefer the currently accepted answer because it's possible to still keep the passwords in your working copy and ignore the files containing them with .gitignore.

Comment: @Henridv I'm not sure how the accepted answer by natacado differs in that respect from my own answer? Both of our answers specifically address the key sentence of the question: "Is there a way to remove all traces of a particular file in your Git history?" - ie they talk about Git history-rewriting. The issue of /how/ NixNinja /should/ supply passwords to his app isn't mentioned either in his question, or in any of the current answers. As it happens, the BFG specifically addresses the issue of unintended consequences, see http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits

Comment: This is a big win right here. After a couple tries, I was able to use this to strip commits containing sensitive information from a private repo very thoroughly and forcefully update the remote repo with the revised history. One side note is that you do have to ensure the tip of your repo (HEAD) is itself clean with no sensitive data as this commit is considered "protected" and won't be revised by this tool. If it isn't, just clean/replace manually and `git commit`. Otherwise, +1 for new tool in developer's toolbox :)

Comment: @Henridv Per my recent comment, it should not break your application as you might anticipate, assuming your application is currently situated at the tip or head of your branch (i.e. latest commit). This tool will explicitly report for your last commit `These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered` while traversing and revising the rest of your commit history. If you needed to rollback, however, then yes you would need to just do a search for `***REMOVED***` in the commit you just rolled back to.

Comment: +1 for BFG (if you have Java installed or don't mind installing it). One catch is that BFG refuses to delete a file if it is contained in HEAD. So it's better to first do a commit where the desired files will be deleted and only then run BFG. After that you can revert that last commit, now it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I have a project where I first wanted the project to work, and THEN went to add stuff like "be able to set the password". So at first there was a structure with "username" and "password" statically intialized in my source. Later I added the stuff to be able to set those. So: Now my source is "clean", but in git-history I have my credentials. As the project is now still private I'll have to run this before I publish. This looks promising!

Comment: `git push --force` is missing

Comment: it seems `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.ext' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` does indeed delete the desired files from HEAD, despite the `--cached` flag  Is this a differentiator for BFG in that it protects HEAD?

Comment: @goofology, yep, see https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm still curious, am I misunderstanding the purpose of `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached *.ext'`?  It seems to function the same as `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm *.ext'` (assuming "clean" working branch")

Comment: If I didn't already love you for this answer, I do now after using the .jar you created: `"You can rewrite history in Git - don't let Trump do it for real!
Trump's administration has lied consistently, to make people give up on ever
being told the truth. Don't give up: https://www.aclu.org/"`

Comment: [Replace text to text of your choosing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15730571/13112739)

Comment: Seems this doesn't work correctly unless you work on your main/master branch and delete all other branches. If you do this on the branch that made the mistake before doing a PR then the PR will try recommit all history it seems.

Answer (score 54):

**`git filter-repo` is now officially recommended over `git filter-branch`**

This is mentioned in the manpage of `git filter-branch` in Git 2.5 itself.

With git filter repo, you could either remove certain files with: [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history/61544937#61544937)

```
pip install git-filter-repo
git filter-repo --path path/to/remove1 --path path/to/remove2 --invert-paths
```

This automatically removes empty commits.

Or you can replace certain strings with: [How to replace a string in whole Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950829/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-whole-git-history/64153992#64153992)

```
git filter-repo --replace-text <(echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx')
```

**If you pushed to GitHub, force pushing is not enough, delete the repository or contact support**

Even if you force push one second afterwards, it is not enough as explained below.

The only valid courses of action are:

- is what leaked a changeable credential like a password?

  - yes: modify your passwords immediately, and consider using more OAuth and API keys!
  - no (naked pics):

    - do you care if all issues in the repository get nuked?

      - no: delete the repository
      - yes:

        - contact support
        - if the leak is very critical to you, to the point that you are willing to get some repository downtime to make it less likely to leak, [make it private](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-repository-visibility#making-a-repository-private) while you wait for GitHub support to reply to you

Force pushing a second later is not enough because:

- GitHub keeps dangling commits for a long time.

  GitHub staff does have the power to delete such dangling commits if you contact them however.

  I experienced this first hand when I [uploaded all GitHub commit emails to a repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/all-github-commit-emails) they asked me to take it down, so I did, and they did a `gc`. Pull requests that contain the data [have to be deleted however](https://github.com/cirosantilli/all-github-commit-emails/tree/f37574b1146cb20d1fadd73830b7bf22da285151#update-2018-02-21): that repo data remained accessible up to one year after initial takedown due to this.

  Dangling commits can be seen either through:

  - the commit web UI: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-dangling/commit/53df36c09f092bbb59f2faa34eba15cd89ef8e83 ([Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929085014/https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-dangling/commit/53df36c09f092bbb59f2faa34eba15cd89ef8e83))
  - the API: https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/test-dangling/commits/53df36c09f092bbb59f2faa34eba15cd89ef8e83 ([Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929084951/https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/test-dangling/commits/53df36c09f092bbb59f2faa34eba15cd89ef8e83))

  One convenient way to get the source at that commit then is to use the download zip method, which can accept any reference, e.g.: https://github.com/cirosantilli/myrepo/archive/SHA.zip
- It is possible to fetch the missing SHAs either by:

  - listing API events with `type": "PushEvent"`. E.g. mine: https://api.github.com/users/cirosantilli/events/public ([Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929085719/https://api.github.com/users/cirosantilli/events/public))
  - more conveniently sometimes, by looking at the SHAs of pull requests that attempted to remove the content
- There are scrappers like http://ghtorrent.org/ and https://www.githubarchive.org/ that regularly pool GitHub data and store it elsewhere.

  I could not find if they scrape the actual commit diff, and that is unlikely because there would be too much data, but it is technically possible, and the NSA and friends likely have filters to archive only stuff linked to people or commits of interest.

If you delete the repository instead of just force pushing however, commits do disappear even from the API immediately and give 404, e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/test-dangling-delete/commits/8c08448b5fbf0f891696819f3b2b2d653f7a3824 This works even if you recreate another repository with the same name.

To test this out, I have created a repo: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-dangling and did:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:cirosantilli/test-dangling.git

touch a
git add .
git commit -m 0
git push

touch b
git add .
git commit -m 1
git push

touch c
git rm b
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push -f
```

See also: [How to remove a dangling commit from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977/how-to-remove-a-dangling-commit-from-github/32840385#32840385)

Comment: If the repository is part of a fork network, **making the repository private or deleting it may not help and may make the problem worse**. Fork networks on GitHub seem to share an internal bare repository, so that commits in one fork are also retrievable through other forks. Making a repository private or deleting it causes a split from the fork network, with the sensitive commits now duplicated in each remaining bare repository. The commits will continue to be accessible through forks until GC has been run on _both_ bare repositories.

Comment: I tried `git filter-repo --replace-text <(echo 'my_password==>xxxxxxxx')` and while it did work, it also made all commits look like they happened today. Is there a way to preserve commit date while changing a file in history?

Comment: @devordem I don't reproduce, author committer dates were maintained for me on git 2.37.2, filter-repo ac039ecc095d, Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Never mind, I later found out it was something else I did that rewrote the commit dates not `git-filter-repo`.

Answer (score 19):

I recommend [this script](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) by David Underhill, worked like a charm for me.

It adds these commands in addition natacado's filter-branch to clean up the mess it leaves behind:

```bash
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --all
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

Full script (all credit to David Underhill)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit

# Author: David Underhill
# Script to permanently delete files/folders from your git repository.  To use 
# it, cd to your repository's root and then run the script with a list of paths
# you want to delete, e.g., git-delete-history path1 path2

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# make sure we're at the root of git repo
if [ ! -d .git ]; then
    echo "Error: must run this script from the root of a git repository"
    exit 1
fi

# remove all paths passed as arguments from the history of the repo
files=$@
git filter-branch --index-filter \
"git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD

# remove the temporary history git-filter-branch
# otherwise leaves behind for a long time
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && \
git reflog expire --all && \
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

The last two commands may work better if changed to the following:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && \
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Comment: Note that your usage of expire and prune are incorrect, if you don't specify the date then it defaults to all commits older than 2 weeks for prune.  What you want is all commits so do: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: @Adam Parkin I'm going to leave the code in the answer the same because it is from the script on David Underhill's site, you could comment there and if he changes it I would change this answer since I really don't know git that well.  The expire command prior to the prune doesn't affect that does it?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: That one won't work for pushed commits.

Comment: Maybe you should just put all the commands in your answer; it would be much more consistent and wouldn't require the mental combining of separate posts :)

Answer (score 19):

You can use `git forget-blob`.

The usage is pretty simple `git forget-blob file-to-forget`. You can get more info here:

- GitHub: [nachoparker/git-forget-blob](https://github.com/nachoparker/git-forget-blob)

It will disappear from all the commits in your history, reflog, tags and so on

I run into the same problem every now and then, and everytime I have to come back to this post and others, that's why I automated the process.

Credits to contributors from Stack Overflow that allowed me to put this together

Answer (score 16):

Here is my solution in windows

> git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f 'filedir/filename'" HEAD
>
> git push --force

make sure that the path is correct
otherwise it won't work

I hope it helps

Answer (score 13):

Use **filter-branch**:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *file_path_relative_to_git_repo*' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

git push origin *branch_name* -f
```

Comment: For windows users, make sure to replace the single quotes to double quotes in the first line.

Answer (score 8):

To be clear: The accepted answer is correct. Try it first. However, it may be unnecessarily complex for some use cases, particularly if you encounter obnoxious errors such as 'fatal: bad revision --prune-empty', or really don't care about the history of your repo.

An alternative would be:

1. cd to project's base branch
2. Remove the sensitive code / file
3. rm -rf .git/ # Remove all git info from
   your code
4. Go to github and delete your repository
5. Follow this guide to push your code to a new repository as you normally would -
   https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

This will of course remove all commit history branches, and issues from both your github repo, and your local git repo. If this is unacceptable you will have to use an alternate approach.

Call this the nuclear option.

Answer (score 5):

In my android project I had **admob_keys.xml** as separated xml file in **app/src/main/res/values/** folder. To remove this sensitive file I used below script and worked perfectly.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch  app/src/main/res/values/admob_keys.xml' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had to do this a few times to-date. Note that this only works on 1 file at a time.

1. Get a list of all commits that modified a file. The one at the bottom will the the first commit:

   `git log --pretty=oneline --branches -- pathToFile`
2. To remove the file from history use the first commit sha1 and the path to file from the previous command, and fill them into this command:

   `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <path-to-file>' -- <sha1-where-the-file-was-first-added>..`

Answer (score 2):

So, It looks something like this:

```
git rm --cached /config/deploy.rb
echo /config/deploy.rb >> .gitignore
```

> Remove cache for tracked file from git and add that file to `.gitignore` list

Answer (score 2):

Considering that OP is using GitHub, if one commits sensitive data into a Git repo, one can remove it entirely from the history by using one of the previous options (read more about them below):

1. The `git filter-repo` tool ([view source on GitHub](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)).
2. The [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) tool (it is open source - [view source on GitHub](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner)).

After one of the previous options, there are additional steps to follow. Check the section **Additional** below.

If the goal is to remove a file that was added in **the most recent unpushed commit**, read the section **Alternative** below.

For future considerations, to prevent similar situations, check the **For the Future** section below.

---

**Option 1**

Using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo). Before moving forward, note that

> If you run `git filter-repo` after stashing changes, you won't be able to retrieve your changes with other stash commands. Before running `git filter-repo`, we recommend unstashing any changes you've made. To unstash the last set of changes you've stashed, run `git stash show -p | git apply -R`. For more information, see [Git Tools - Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning).

Let us now remove one file from the history of one's repo and add it to `.gitignore` (to prevent re-committing it again).

Before moving forward, make sure that one has `git filter-repo` installed ([read here how to install it](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it)), and that one has a local copy of one's repo (if that is not the case, [see here how to clone a repository](https://Cloning%20a%20repository)).

1. Open GitBash and access the repository.

   ```
   cd YOUR-REPOSITORY
   ```
2. (Optional) Backup the `.git/config` file.
3. Run

   ```
   git filter-repo --invert-paths --path PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
   ```

   replace `PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` with **the path to the file you want to remove, not just its filename** to:

   - Force Git to process, but not check out the entire history of every branch and tag.
   - Remove the specified file (as well as empty commits generated as a result)
   - Remove some configs (such as remote URL stored in the `.git/config` file)
   - **Overwrite one's existing tags**.
4. Add the file with sensitive data to `.gitignore`

   ```
   echo "YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" >> .gitignore

   git add .gitignore

   git commit -m "Add YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA to .gitignore"
   ```
5. Check if everything was removed from one's repository history, and that all branches are checked out. Only then move to the next step.
6. Force-push the local changes  to overwrite your repository on GitHub.com, as well as all the branches you've pushed up. A force push is required to remove sensitive data from your commit history. Read the first note at the bottom of this answer for more details one this.

   ```
   git push origin --force --all
   ```

---

**Option 2**

Using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). This is faster and simpler than `git filter-branch`.

For example, to remove one's file with sensitive data and leave your latest commit untouched, run

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
```

To replace all text listed in `passwords.txt` wherever it can be found in your repository's history, run

```
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
```

After the sensitive data is removed, one must force push one's changes to GitHub.

```
git push --force
```

---

**Additional**

After using one of the options above:

1. [Contact GitHub Support](https://support.github.com/contact?tags=docs-generic).
2. (If working with a team) Tell them to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), not merge, any branches they created off of one's old (tainted) repository history. One merge commit could reintroduce some or all of the tainted history that one just went to the trouble of purging.
3. After some time has passed and you're confident that one had no unintended side effects, one can force all objects in one's local repository to be dereferenced and garbage collected with the following commands (using Git 1.8.5 or newer):

   ```
   git for-each-ref --format="delete %(refname)" refs/original | git update-ref --stdin

   git reflog expire --expire=now --all

   git gc --prune=now
   ```

---

**Alternative**

If the file was added with the most recent commit, and one has not pushed to GitHub.com, one can delete the file and amend the commit:

1. Open GitBash and access the repository.

   ```
   cd YOUR-REPOSITORY.l
   ```
2. To remove the file, enter `git rm --cached`:

   ```
   git rm --cached GIANT_FILE
   # Stage our giant file for removal, but leave it on disk
   ```
3. Commit this change using `--amend -CHEAD`:

   ```
   git commit --amend -CHEAD
   # Amend the previous commit with your change
   # Simply making a new commit won't work, as you need
   # to remove the file from the unpushed history as well
   ```
4. Push one's commits to GitHub.com:

   ```
   git push
   # Push our rewritten, smaller commit
   ```

---

**For the Future**

In order to prevent sensitive data to be exposed, other good practices include:

- Use a visual program to commit the changes. There are various alternatives (such as [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/), [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), ...) and it could be easier to track the changes.
- Avoid the catch-all commands `git add .` and `git commit -a`. Instead, use `git add filename` and `git rm filename` to individually stage files.
- Use `git add --interactive` to individually review and stage changes within each file.
- Use `git diff --cached` to review the changes that one has staged for commit. This is the exact diff that `git commit` will produce as long as one doesn't use the `-a` flag.
- Generate Secret Keys in secure hardware (HSM boxes, hardware keys - like Yubikey / Solokey), that never leaves it.
- Train the team on [x508](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

---

**Notes:**

- When one force pushes, it rewrites the repository history, which removes sensitive data from the commit history. That may overwrite commits that other people have based their work on.
- For this answer one used content from some GitHub posts:

  - [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)
  - [About large files on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github)