# How do I delete a commit from a branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-reset

How do I delete a commit from my branch history? Should I use `git reset --hard HEAD`?

Comment: I think this is **not** a duplicate of [Git undo last commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit) as it asks how to delete **any** commit from a branch. I also think non of the answers actually address this question. They all rewind the last commits, not `cherry-pick` and `delete` a single commit that may occurred a while ago.

Comment: @Chris, the answer with `git rebase -i HEAD~10` does address the question, as it does let you arbitrarily pick commits to delete. Git applies the commits in the range you specify one-by-one, ignoring commits you have removed from the log. I used this command today to get rid of the second and third most recent commits to my repo while keeping the top one. I agree that none of the other answers are satisfactory.

Comment: @MST yes, I should have said, non of the options in the accepted answer address this question, but you are absolutely right - that command seems to work

Comment: I think `git reset --soft HEAD~1` is exactly what you need.
In such case you will undo commit and save your work. `reset --hard` will remove commit completely.

Comment: command: git log | head -n 1 | git revert

Comment: Luckily, I could just write an empty commit message and with that, the commit was not commited :), so that I did not need to delete it. TL/DR: I had by chance run the command `git commit -a`, thinking it was a short form of `git commit --amend` (which it is not) and was in a new empty commit message. I could just cancel the editor (using `:wq` in vim) with the empty message and git did not create the commit and instead return `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD~2  then
git push origin branchName 
you need to push to after git reset --soft HEAD~2  this command or the branch history will not update

Answer (score 5496, accepted):

**Careful:** `git reset --hard` **WILL DELETE YOUR WORKING DIRECTORY CHANGES**.
Be sure to **stash any local changes you want to keep** before running this command.

Assuming you are sitting on that commit, then this command will wack it...

```bash
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The `HEAD~1` means the commit before head.

Or, you could look at the output of `git log`, find the commit id of the commit you want to back up to, and then do this:

```bash
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>
```

---

If you already pushed it, you will need to do a force push to get rid of it...

```bash
git push origin HEAD --force
```

**However**, if others may have pulled it, then you would be better off starting a new branch.  Because when they pull, it will just merge it into their work, and you will get it pushed back up again.

If you already pushed, it may be better to use `git revert`, to create a "mirror image" commit that will undo the changes.  However, both commits will be in the log.

---

FYI: `git reset --hard HEAD` is great if you want to get rid of WORK IN PROGRESS.It will reset you back to the most recent commit, and erase all the changes in your working tree and index.

**`git stash` does the same except you can restore it later if you need**, versus permanently delete with reset hard mode. Check your stashes by using `git stash list` and `git stash show 'stash@123'`

---

Lastly, if you need to find a commit that you "deleted", it is typically present in `git reflog` unless you have garbage collected your repository.

Comment: `HEAD~1` or just `HEAD^`.  If you pushed, you should use `git revert` instead.

Comment: Obviously you can also use `HEAD~n` to "go back" `n` commits from your head. Maybe from this point you can interpreted `... --hard HEAD` also as `HEAD~0` => deleting work in progress.

Comment: @beamrider9 That is what `--hard` means.

Comment: @beamrider9 imho git rebase is almost always the better way to delete commits (as described in Greg Hewgill's answer) -- not least because rebase does in fact include a big warning that you will be deleting stuff 4realz.

Comment: maybe this should be modified to mention --soft ?

Comment: this doesn't delete changes from the commit tree though. The OP asked for an already made commit. If you `reset --hard`, and check the `log --oneline --all`, the commits still remain in the tree. How do we delete these commits from tree? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough documentation here. The only thing I'd add is that rebase typically is used to deal with multiple branches rather than deleting a single commit in a single branch.

Comment: use `reset --soft` to delete local commit WITHOUT reverting work in progress!

Comment: Glad I read the comments to learn that this answer doesn't actually answer the question, there should be NO leftovers in the repo "as if I didn't make that commit."

Comment: You sure deserve an upvote because I have looked this up atleast 5 times in the last year

Comment: Confirming that in Sept 2015 this worked for me `git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>` to make the last commit "like it never even happend"

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is recommending `git reset --hard ...` and then proceeds to explain how one should watch out for working directory changes etc. Well, why not use the more apt and less dangerous `git reset [--soft]` (i.e. soft or mixed reset) instead?

Comment: Dropping the commit through a rebase is a less aggressive solution to achieve the same goal. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: I always that `HEAD~1` means 'Go to the previous commit'. But the 'Go to' is a result of the command. `HEAD~1` just means 'previous commit'. The command `reset --hard HEAD~1` means Go to <this previous commit>`

Comment: ```HEAD``` is a reference to the currently checked out commit. ```HEAD^``` references it's parent.  ```HEAD^^``` references it's grandparent.  ```HEAD~N``` references it's Nth parent.  If you look at ```git log``` you will see that ```HEAD~3``` is the 4th entry down.   And yes, these can be used on any git operation that requires a commit as an argument.  A branch, by the way, is just another reference to a commit :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318688/2694784 is better as it shows how to remove a commit which is not on the top.

Comment: I too had what @Igbanam experienced,  After a `reset --hard` on the commit I wanted, `git log --oneline --all` still showed the commits I wanted to discard. Turns out once I did a `git stash pop` those commits were removed from  `git log --all`. I had a stash in one of the deleted commits.

Comment: @dbagnara I don't see my commit in `git log --all` anymore, yet I'm still able to `git reset --hard deleted-commit-id`

Comment: Sorry @Wassadamo, I am out of my depth here and unable to help you.

Comment: So how do you delete it from reflogs?

Comment: We should be careful with `git push --force`. We can do just the same with `git push --force-with-lease`, except from losing unknown commits from the remote. Requires to perform `git fetch` or similar if there are commits in the remote that weren't fetched locally.

Answer (score 913):

If you have not yet pushed the commit anywhere, you can use [`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to remove that commit. First, find out how far back that commit is (approximately). Then do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

The `~N` means rebase the last `N` commits (`N` must be a number, for example `HEAD~10`). Then, you can edit the file that Git presents to you to delete the offending commit. On saving that file, Git will then rewrite all the following commits as if the one you deleted didn't exist.

The Git Book has a good [section on rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) with pictures and examples.

Be careful with this though, because if you change something that you *have* pushed elsewhere, another approach will be needed unless you are planning to do a force push.

Comment: Note: If you happen to have any --no-ff merges in that last batch of commits, rebase will butcher them :( This is mentioned under -p on [this page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html). The problem is, if you replace -i with -p, you no longer get that pop up with the choices for "edit this commit, sqush that one", etc etc. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Is this better than the "reset hard" answer as it won't delete the files, just the mistaken commit message? Because it appears to have deleted my files. If deleting the file is supposed to happen, please add that as a clear warning!

Comment: What if you have pushed it? (just me using the remote repo)

Comment: @Costa you can use `push -f` to force the push and replace the remote branch with your local one. If it's just your own remote repo, no problem. The trouble starts if somebody else has fetched in the meantime.

Comment: @Bukov The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_bugs) says you can use both `-i` and `-p`, but if you do, "Editing commits and rewording their commit messages should work fine, but attempts to reorder commits tend to produce counterintuitive results."  I'm not sure how well deleting commits would work, but you could try it and then do a `reset --hard` to before the rebase (using the reflog) if it doesn't work out properly.

Comment: Or `git rebase -i 592d26e9131e0a5a9b6ada78ab1574688cbbf9b7^` while `592d26e9131e0a5a9b6ada78ab1574688cbbf9b7` is the id of an earliest commit you want to delete.

Comment: When it deletes the commit does it also delete the changes (like `--hard` in the original post) or does it leave them intact but uncommitted (c.f. `--soft`)?

Comment: @dumbledad: With `rebase -i`, the changes corresponding to the deleted commit are not preserved.

Comment: rebase will not work if you have stashed changes

Answer (score 718):

Another possibility is one of my personal favorite commands:

```
git rebase -i <commit>~1
```

This will start the rebase in interactive mode `-i` at the point just before the commit you want to whack. The editor will start up listing all of the commits since then. Delete the line containing the commit you want to obliterate and save the file. Rebase will do the rest of the work, deleting only that commit, and replaying all of the others back into the log.

Comment: thx, btw if you run into any issues (like empty commits) you can use `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Even easier:

    `git rebase -i HEAD~1`

Comment: Wowzers. `git rebase -i HEAD~1` really cleaned the repo up a lot! It's hard to tell exactly what it did, but the whole thing looks a lot neater. A little alarming, actually.

Comment: When a commit is empty, git rebase will display that line commented out (`#`). If you don't uncomment that line, git will delete the commit when rebasing. Deleting the empty commit is actually exactly what I was trying to do, but if you want to keep yours, un-comment out the line first.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the commit is not obliterated, merely removed from the list. If you mess up, you can get the commit back using the [reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html).

Comment: Is deleting the line the same as d/drop?

Comment: @dragonmnl deleting or modifying pushed commits is something that I understand is not recommended

Comment: I had merged instead of rebasing and my pull request showed other changes then mine. running git rebase -i HEAD~1 cleaned it up. Thanks to mmell

Comment: First time ever I dared to use `rebase` and it worked smoothly.

Comment: That _worked_ that is, I was able to remove a commit but then I just can't push the results so it's just completely useless. Maybe because I already pushed earlier?

Comment: After rebasing, you will probably have to force push. Suggest doing `git push --force-with-lease` as this is a safer force push. 

Also often you can replace `HEAD` with just an `@` (e.g., `git rebase -i @~1`)

Comment: You should add a disclaimer (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338758/6395770)) that this won't work smoothly if you have already pushed your changes

Comment: I am getting error as- "fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~1'"

Answer (score 473):

**I'm appending this answer because I don't see why anyone who has just tried to commit work would want to delete all that work because of some mistake using Git!**

If you want to keep your work and just 'undo' that commit command (you caught before pushing to repo):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

**Do not use the --hard** flag unless you want to destroy your work in progress since the last commit.

Comment: Here's an example of why: you do a small piece of work on a development server that you commit. Then it turns out that that server doesn't have outgoing HTTPS access, so you can't push the commit anywhere. Easiest to just pretend it never happened, and redo the patch from your local machine.

Comment: @KarthikBose there would always be the reflog. even after `git reset --hard HEAD~1` your previous latest commit would be available via reflog (until you expire it); see also here: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: Maybe I'm using git wrong, but one situation I'd like the `--hard` option for is when I've got multiple remote branches and I pushed to the wrong branch. Say I've got a `master` branch and a `staging` branch, I do work on a local branch, but then accidentally merge and push into master, and then realize I did the wrong thing. I'd then want to restore master's HEAD to the second most recent commit **and** want to remove all trace of that faulty push from master, as it's not **supposed** to be in master

Comment: you could just as easily do git commit --amend in this scenario which is way less confusing

Comment: Thanks. This answer should be ranked higher or included in the accepted answer. Deleting a commit != reverting a commit.

Comment: @RandolphCarter: you will still lose any uncommitted changes though.

Comment: @Rob, one example is when you accidentally commit a file that contains a secret (e.g. a password) that should never be in source control. The local commit must be *destroyed*, not just undone, so it will never get pushed to the server.

Comment: This worked great!  I did not want to undo everything, only a few folders in my last couple commits.  HARD could have worked, but I would of had to save off all my changes that I wanted to keep and patch them in latter.  SOFT removed the local commits.  And "git reset HEAD -- ." was also necessary to remove staged changed.  Then I could remove all the bad things manually, and everything else - my other changes - were left intact.

Comment: On Visual Studio, for those who are interested, it says Reset (Mixed) with changes.  Gives you back your commits, i.e. to the one you have selected in the non-synced ones.

Answer (score 257):

**Removing an entire commit**

```
git rebase -p --onto SHA^ SHA
```

Obviously replace "SHA" with the reference you want to get rid of. The "^" in that command is literal.

http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#change_deep

Comment: Thank you for this link! I was wondering, after running this, why do I still see the commit SHA in my git reflog?

Comment: `-p, --preserve-merges`
           Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments
           to merge commits are not preserved.

Comment: It says, "replace SHA with the reference you want to get rid of" but the line has SHA in there twice. Here is what I did. 
git rebase -p --onto 5ca8832c120^ 5ca8832c120
But nothing changed. Am I supposed to use the same SHA twice? If not, then which is the SHA for the commit to be removed and what is the other SHA supposed to be?

Comment: to be specific, this method removes ENTIRE commit, including files (not desired in my case)

Comment: @Rubicksman ^ must be escaped (^^) on windows (cmd window) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955985/what-does-the-caret-character-mean

Comment: on mac: `git rebase --onto SHA~ SHA`

Comment: `-p`
`[DEPRECATED: use --rebase-merges instead]`

Comment: SO needs a button that says "this is actually the answer"

Comment: @CesarVarela it already does (the green check mark).

Answer (score 137):

Say we want to remove commits 2 & 4 from the repo. (Higher the the number newer the commit; 0 is the oldest commit and 4 is the latest commit)

```
commit 0 : b3d92c5
commit 1 : 2c6a45b
commit 2 : <any_hash>
commit 3 : 77b9b82
commit 4 : <any_hash>
```

Note: **You need to have admin rights over the repo** since you are using `--hard` and `-f`.

- `git checkout b3d92c5` Checkout the last usable commit.
- `git checkout -b repair` Create a new branch to work on.
- `git cherry-pick 77b9b82` Run through commit 3.
- `git cherry-pick 2c6a45b` Run through commit 1.
- `git checkout master` Checkout master.
- `git reset --hard b3d92c5` Reset master to last usable commit.
- `git merge repair` Merge our new branch onto master.
- `git push -f origin master` Push master to the remote repo.

Comment: last step should be `git push -f origin master` there is no option `--hard`

Comment: I guess `commit 0` is older than `commit 1`. Please could you tell me why first run through `commit 3` (by cherry-pick) and then by `commit 1`? After checkout of `b3d92cd` (`commit 0`) I would expect cherry-pick `commit 1`, then `commit 3`. Thanks.

Comment: @JarekC I think the top-most commit is the newest commit here, unless I'm seeing something wrong...

Comment: This is mostly right but kind of wrong. I just followed this process and had to tweak it a bit. Clarification: `commit 0` is the newest commit, `commit 4` is the oldest. Start by checking out `commit 5`, just before the commit that you don't want. Then `cherry-pick` `commit 3`, then `cherry-pick` `commit 1`, then do it for `commit 0`. Then checkout master and reset it to `commit 5` and follow the rest of the steps.

Comment: Good thorough and safe approach. Managing the changes on a separate branch means you can even do interactive rebasing on the `repair` branch and combine commits before merging back in to `master`. The only comment I have is that you can consolidate the first two steps: `git checkout -b repair b3d92c5`

Comment: @JoshuaSwain As per my understanding of this answer, commit 4 is the latest one and commit 0 is the oldest one. One reason for that is - 

He is merging master with repair branch in the end so that the final tree of master looks as if commit 2 and commit 4 were not there. So far so good?

Now before doing this merge he reset the master to commit 0 and then merging the two good commits from repair branch. If commit 4 was the oldest then he woudn't have reset master to b3d92c5 instead would have reset to 77b9b82

Comment: In your example, you started from "commit 0", but the last usable commit is "commit 1" right?
So I would expect to checkout "commit 1" (first step) and then only cherry-pick "commit 3" after creating "repair" branch.
Am I missing something?

Comment: was the answer I am searching for! would recommend to change the order of the list as newer commits are usually displayed first, followed by older. the ordering made it hard for me to understand and adapt your solution

Comment: I upvoted this answer because 1) the other answers assume the poster is only interested in redoing the latest commits 2) this shows a more flexible overall approach to changing your work as opposed to merely working linearly.

Answer (score 77):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Here '2' is the number of commits you want to rebase.

```
'git rebase -i HEAD`
```

if you want to rebase all the commits.

Then you will be able to choose one of these options.

`p, pick = use commit`

```
r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
```

```
e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
```

```
s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
```

```
f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
```

```
x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

```
d, drop = remove commit
```

These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
Note that empty commits are commented out

You can simply remove that commit using option "d" or Removing a line that has your commit.

Comment: In the latest git version there is no more option *d*. You need just remove lines with commits from rebase to delete them.

Answer (score 66):

#[Quick Answer]

You have many alternatives, for example:

- **Alternative 1:**

  ```
   git rebase -i <YourCommitId>~1
  ```

  > Change YourCommitId for the number of the commit which you want to revert back to.
- **Alternative 2:**

  ```
   git reset --hard YourCommitId
   git push <origin> <branch> --force
  ```

  > Change YourCommitId for the number of the commit which you want to revert back to.

  > I don't recommend this option because you may lose your in progress work.
- **Alternative 3:**

  ```
   git reset --soft HEAD~1
  ```

  > You can keep your work and only undo the commit.

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~1` worked perfectly for me. Makes sure I don't lost to changes from that commit. Thank you for your clear answer.

Answer (score 59):

If you didn't publish changes, to remove latest commit, you can do

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

(note that this would also remove all uncommitted changes; use with care).

If you already published to-be-deleted commit, use [git revert](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)

```
$ git revert HEAD
```

Comment: That didn't work. When I git log, everything is still there, no matter why I do it just adds more commits. I wanna clean up the history.

Comment: @Costa: What didn't work (i.e. which version did you use), and how did you git log?

Comment: I've tried almost everything on this Q&A. (I tried git revert HEAD, most recently) My git log: `tree = log --all --graph --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(dim black)%s%C(reset)%C(bold red)%d%C(reset) %C(green)by %an, %ar%C(reset)'`

Comment: @Costa: Note that with first version (using `git reset --hard HEAD^`) you "remove" commit only from current branch (actually move branch pointer), if there was some other branch this commit was on it would still be there.  "Removing" commit with `git reset` just moves back branch pointer, making commit *dangling* and available for pruning... if not referenced by other ref (other branch, remote-tracking branch, or tag).  Or did you use `git revert HEAD`?

Comment: I just want to delete the commits (like as if they never existed). I went off on some weird coding adventure, with several new commits, and it all ended up being trash. How can I just erase those from my git log?

Answer (score 59):

**Forcefully Change History**

Assuming you don't just want to delete the last commit, but you want to delete specific commits of the last n commits, go with:

`git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits to go back>`, so `git rebase -i HEAD~5` if you want to see the last five commits.

Then in the text editor change the word `pick` to `drop` next to every commit you would like to remove. Save and quit the editor. Voila!

**Additively Change History**

Try `git revert <commit hash>`. [Revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert) will create a *new* commit that undoes the specified commit.

Comment: `drop` keyword is not defined. To delete a commit just remove the whole line.

Comment: For me drop was defined as a keyword, but doing a drop didn't seem to remove the commit from the history.  Removing the line from the interactive rebase however did.

Comment: I deleted the line as suggested in several places: it didn't do anything. Replacing the word `pick` with `drop` did delete the commit. Note: the instructions are in the remarked-out section in the bottom portion of the text editor's contents. Using `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`

Answer (score 57):

```
git reset --hard commitId

git push <origin> <branch> --force
```

PS: CommitId refers the one which you want to revert back to

Comment: git push --force <origin> <branchName>. as without mentioning branch name it might change all file on remote.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to fix up your latest commit, you can undo the commit, and unstage the files in it, by doing:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

This will return your repository to its state before the git add commands that staged the files. Your changes will be in your working directory. HEAD~1 refers to the commit below the current tip of the branch.

If you want to uncommit N commits, but keep the code changes in your working directory:

```
git reset HEAD~N
```

If you want to get rid of your latest commit, and do not want to keep the code changes, you can do a "hard" reset.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Likewise, if you want to discard the last N commits, and do not want to keep the code changes:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~N
```

Comment: I tried this and I got my latest commit removed but now when I push to the remote repository it says I have to pull before push. So I pulled and then pushed but when I pulled I again got the commit that I just removed because I pushed it before to remote. What should I do now?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to delete the commit you are currently on but don't want to delete the data-

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

If you want to delete the commit you are currently on and want to delete the related data-

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

PS: these commands will only delete the local commits.

Comment: best answer . Nice and clean

Answer (score 22):

To delete in local branch, use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

To delete in a remote branch, use

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Answer (score 17):

Source: https://gist.github.com/sagarjethi/c07723b2f4fa74ad8bdf229166cf79d8

### Delete the last commit

**For example  your last  commit**

git push origin +aa61ab32^:master

Now you want to delete this commit then an Easy way to do this following

Steps

1. First reset the branch to the parent of the current commit
2. Force-push it to the remote.

> ```
> git reset HEAD^ --hard
>
> git push origin -f
> ```

For particular commit, you want to reset is following

```
git reset bb676878^ --hard

git push origin -f
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're an **IntelliJ** user, the interface is simply awesome. With a **single click**, you can see the effect immediately at the same time. Shortcut to this place: `Cmd + 9` on MacOS.

[image]

Comment: This question isn't about intelliJ, but about Git itself.

Comment: if you're using intellij this is the fastest and easiest way, but remember that you'll have to force push because you've changed the git history

Answer (score 13):

Here I just post one clear pipeline to do so

Step1: Use git log to get the commit ID.

```
git log
```

[image]

Step2: Use git reset to go back to the former version:

```
git reset --hard <your commit id>
```

Comment: [`git log origin/master..`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits) to get unpushed commit.  `git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>` to sit on the commit, `get reset --hard HEAD~1` to delete the commit.

Answer (score 11):

All the commands above restore the state of your work tree and index as they were before making the commit, but do not restore the state of the repository. If you look at it, the "removed" commit is not actually removed, it is simply not the one on the tip of the current branch.

I think that there are no means to remove a commit with [porcelain commands](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-1.html). The only way is to remove it from the log and reflog and then to execute a `git prune --expire -now`.

Comment: The order in which answers are shown on StackOverflow is not fixed. Please do not refer to “All the commands above”. Make your own answer self-contained.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct. `git prune` [is actually one of the "porcelain" commands](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_ancillary_commands). Also, it is rare that you would want to completely clear out your reflog (one use case is to remove sensitive info from your repo, but like I said, that's a rare use case). More often than not, you'll want to keep old commits around in the reflog, in case you need to recover data. See [Pro Git: 9.7 Git Internals - Maintenance and Data Recovery](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep the history, showing the commit and the revert, you should use:

```
git revert GIT_COMMIT_HASH
```

enter the message explaining why are you reverting and then:

```
git push
```

When you issue `git log` you'll see both the "wrong" commit and revert log messages.

Comment: Yes, but the OP was clear that that's not what they want.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another way to do this:

Checkout the branch you want to revert, then reset your local working copy back to the commit that you want to be the latest one on the remote server (everything after it will go bye-bye). To do this, in SourceTree I right-clicked on the and selected "Reset BRANCHNAME to this commit". I think the command line is:

```
git reset --hard COMMIT_ID
```

Since you just checked out your branch from remote, you're not going to have any local changes to worry about losing. But this would lose them if you did.

Then navigate to your repository's local directory and run this command:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false \
push -v -f --tags REPOSITORY_NAME BRANCHNAME:BRANCHNAME
```

This will erase all commits after the current one in your local repository but only for that one branch.

Answer (score 9):

The mistake:

I `git rebase -i --root`'ed my branch, ignorantly thinking I could reword the first commit differing from the master (the *GitHub for Windows* default view is the comparison to master, hiding it's entirety).

I grew a Silicon Valley beard while 900+ commits loaded themselves into Sublime. Exiting with no changes, I charged my battery then proceeded to shave, as all 900+ individual commits nonchalantly rebased - resetting their commit times to now.

Determined to beat Git and preserve the original times, I deleted this local repository and re-cloned from the remote.

Now it had re-added a most recent unneeded commit to master I wished to remove, so proceeded like so.

Exhausting the options:

I didn't wish to `git revert` - it would create an additional commit, giving Git the upper hand.

`git reset --hard HEAD` did nothing, after checking the `reflog`, the last and only `HEAD` was the clone - Git wins.

To get the most recent SHA, I checked the remote repository on github.com - minor win.

After thinking `git reset --hard <SHA>` had worked, I updated another branch to master and 1... 2... poof! the commit was back - Git wins.

Checking back out to master, time to try `git rebase -i <SHA>`, then remove the line... to no avail, sad to say. "*If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST*". Ah...glossed over new feature *troll the n00b* in the [2.8.3 release notes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swukg8jqui0wc69/2.8.3.txt).

The solution:

`git rebase -i <SHA>` then `d, drop = remove commit`.

To verify, I checked out to another branch, and voila - no hiding commit to fetch/pull from the master.

https://twitter.com/holman/status/706006896273063936

Good day to you.

Answer (score 8):

If you just messed up your last commit (wrong message, forgot to add some changes) and want to fix it before pushing it to a public repo why not use:

```
git commit --amend -m "New message here"
```

If you have newly staged changes they'll be combined with the last commit (that you're trying to get rid of) and will replace that commit.

Of course if you amend a commit after you've pushed it, you're rewriting history so if you do that be sure to understand the implications.

You can also pass the '--no-edit' option instead of '-m' if you would prefer to use the previous commit's message.

Docs:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: That's not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 7):

If you've already pushed, first find the commit you want to be at HEAD *($GIT_COMMIT_HASH_HERE)*, then run the following:

```
git reset --hard $GIT_COMMIT_HASH_HERE
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Then each place the repo has been cloned, run:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 7):

What I do usually when I commit and push (if anyone pushed his commit this solve the problem):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1

git push -f origin
```

hope this help

Answer (score 7):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

You will be now at previous head. Pull the branch. Push new code. Commit will be removed from git

Comment: Unless you have already pushed the changes. In that case hard reset will not clean up your remote. In that case rebase is the good option

Answer (score 6):

Reset on local branch

```
git reset --hard HEAD~<Number of commit> So git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Force push to origin

```
git push -f origin
```

Answer (score 5):

I have already pushed. Need to return some commits back remotly.
Have tried many variations, 
but only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41927515/6352712) from [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425964/justin) via git bush is working fine for me:

```
git reset --hard $GIT_COMMIT_HASH_HERE
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// display git commit log    
$ git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

// show last two commit and open in your default editor
// then delete second commit line and save it
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Reference: [How to delete a commit in git, local and remote](https://ncona.com/2011/07/how-to-delete-a-commit-in-git-local-and-remote/)

Answer (score 4):

Take backup of your code in to temp folder. Following command will reset same as server.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -f
git pull
```

If you want to keep your changes , and remove recent commits

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git pull
```

Answer (score 3):

allow you delete commit and doesn't remove  your current files:

```
git reset --soft Id commit
```

then use forcefully push the local changes:

```
git push -f origin nameBranch
```

Answer (score 3):

Use IntelliJ drop commit as one of the easiest and most straightforward solution.
You can access it from the bottom left corner:
[image: access git window in IntelliJ]

Then you can select the commit and right click on it you will get this menu:
[image: form the menu]
Then you can choose: the drop commit option.

Answer (score 2):

[image: delete local commit]

As you can see on above image i want to delete revert"test change 2" commit(SHA1 ID: **015b5220c50e3dfbb1063f23789d92ae1d3481a2**(you can get SHA1 ID by using `gitk` command in git bash)).

For that i can use(all below command work on local only. you need to push after delete):

1. `git reset --hard 515b5220c50e3dfbb1063f23789d92ae1d3481a2` //it back-up you to that commit (SHA1 ID of **test change 4** commit is **515b5220c50e3dfbb1063f23789d92ae1d3481a2**)
2. `git reset --hard HEAD~1` // it back-up you before one commit.
3. `git reset --hard HEAD^`  // To remove the last commit from git

after delete:

[image: after delete commit]

Answer (score 1):

git reset --hard

git push origin HEAD --force

**If one or more of the commits is tagged, delete the tag(s) first.** Otherwise the tagged commit is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

For me **rebase** did the trick

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~98

# Delete everything except for the most recent commit on the shown editor caused by "rebase"

$ git push origin -f production-static
```

**NOTE:**
After forcing the push to reduce my comments. I then pushed another set of files and then I tried pulled with the same "repository & branch" on another computer. Surprisingly there is no conflict. This became my way to reduce repository size while avoiding pull conflicts on my other locals that uses the same git

Answer (score 1):

With more than 30 ansers here, I'll keep it simple with what works for me

Deleting the **.git folder** may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state, it is very safe to do it as in the following:

Checkout

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
```

Add all the files

```
git add -A
```

Commit the changes

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Delete the branch

```
git branch -D master
```

Rename the current branch to master

```
git branch -m master
```

Finally, force update your repository

```
git push -f origin master
```

PS: this will not keep your old commit history around.

Answer (score 1):

Removing a commit is very easy, but it is better to save it somewhere maybe there is some code line which would be useful. (I write this because something similar had happen to me some days ago).

So best is to start with some

```
git reset --soft HEAD~N
```

with N for the commits to go back and than some

```
git stash push -m "some useful comment"
```

to save a patch for further use. Than your are the N commits back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not pushed to the remote repository, you could re-clone the repository. This has been my method of choice a few times.

Comment: @LucasHuang No, it's not: "when I do a push in the *future*, my changes will not push to the remote branch"

Answer (score 0):

use git revert  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert .It will revert all code then you can do next commit.Then head will point to that last commit. reverted commits never delete but it will not affect on you last commit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my magic code for this pupose is this one:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Test it and tell me. I have tried a few different ones, but this one was the only that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Using VS Code's Git Graph Extension:
Checkout to that specific branch and you can drop a commit from history.

https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph

[image: Git Graph Drop Commit]