# Delete commits in Git nad Undo changes

Tags: git

i have a file (script.js)e with this code :

```
alert("Hello");
```

i added the file to index then commited it :

```
git add script.js
git commit -m "say hello"
```

i changed the script to this

```
alert("Hello adam");
```

and then commited the changes
now i want to undo last commit with this commande

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

so the last commit was deleted but the file still contain the name "adam"
why?
what i want is this : when i reset a commit i wan to delet last changes on my file

Comment: Its because you used a soft reset. Soft reset will un-commit the files (still have them tracked) but leave them intact. You can either do a hard reset, checkout the file, or checkout the previous commit. If you choose to do the last two, I recommend doing a git log so you can see which hash you want to checkout/reset to.

Comment: i commited changes and i want to undo it

Comment: how can i do that with code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528245/7976758

Answer (score 3):

`git reset` has three modes, "hard", "soft", and "mixed" which describe what happens to the working tree (ie. your files) and the staging area.

- `--soft` leaves both the staging area and your files alone.
- `--hard` discards all changes in the staging area and files.
- `--mixed` resets the index but leaves the working tree alone.

With that in mind, let's look at what you did.

---

Let's say your repo looks like this.

```
A - B [master]
```

You commit `alert("Hello");`, that becomes commit C.

```
A - B - C [master]
```

You commit `alert("Hello adam");`, that becomes commit D.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
```

You run `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. `HEAD~1` is commit C with `alert("Hello");`. So `master` has moved back to commit C undoing the `alert("Hello adam");` commit.

Since you used `--soft` both the index and files will remain the same. The files will still say `alert("Hello adam");` and you will see a diff. This gives you the opportunity to redo the commit.

---

Instead if you want to revise the immediately previous commit, use `git commit --amend`. This rewrites the previous commit. In your current state with C checked out and `alert("Hello adam");` uncommitted, you can `git commit -a` to rewrite commit C with your new change.

```
A - B - C1 [master]
     \        
      C
```

The old C will eventually be garbage collected.

In general, if you want to revise the previous commit, simply make your edits and then `git commit --amend` them to the previous commit. More involved rewriting of history would involve an "interactive rebase". See [`Rewriting History` in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more.

---

Incidentally, `git --soft HEAD~1` is a form of "redo". It allows you to undo the previous commit while retaining its changes so you can edit them and commit them anew. Here's some useful aliases to make these commands easier to understand.

```
[alias]
    # Undo the last commit
    undo = reset --hard HEAD^

    # Undo the last commit, but leave its changes in the working copy
    # so we can redit them.
    redo = reset --soft HEAD^

    # Throw out all changes
    clear = reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: you sad : --hard discards all changes in the staging area and files.
but hard work only when you add a file to stage area and you did not commit yet !

Comment: in my case i commited changes and i want to undo it

Comment: This was super detailed. :)

Answer (score 0):

--hard discards all changes in the staging area and files. but hard work only when you add a file to stage area and you did not commit yet
so to undo a commit you should add the hash

```
git reset --hard HashOfCommit
```

Comment: Did you commit or push? reset will remove the commit, the type of reset you do will either leave you with tracked changes or not....

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your comments to existing answers, you have probably already pushed your unwanted commit to the remote repository. In that case you have to do following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push --force
```

Push with force option will **overwrite** state that you have on your remote repository for current branch. Note that you should not use this command on public branches (shared with other developers), because it will most likely lead to conflicts.