# What's the difference between `git reset` and `git reset --soft`?

Tags: git, git-reset

I am looking online to see if there is a difference between:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

and

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

I see some good stuff on the subject but nothing that seems to differentiate between the two above commands.

[What's the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard)

Comment: The answer is in the question you linked to. Specifically the sentence that says "Note: `--mixed` is the default option". With that information and an extensive explanation of what `reset --mixed` and `reset --soft` do, there should be clarity.

Comment: it answers the question as a sidebar sure

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet, these two are equivalent:

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~1

git reset HEAD~1
```

because `--mixed` is the default. And the difference between `git reset --mixed` and `git reset --soft` is discussed in depth [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard).