# Git reset soft vs mixed - why use --mixed at all?

Tags: git, git-reset

When using `git reset` why would one prefer to use `git reset --mixed` over `git reset --soft` if the first option means re-adding files that `--soft` already takes care of ?

Also, regarding the difference between the 2 options - If I were **not** to use `git reset --soft` (e.g. as an exercise), is there a case where `git reset --mixed` && `git add` won't be able to mimic `git reset --soft` behavior ?

---

Edit: I know there are similar questions but they don't dive into edge cases where `git reset --mixed` together with `git add` might not be equivalent to `git reset --soft` and they mostly summarize known documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard)

Comment: @CodeCaster No. It states the difference but it doesn't show scenarios where one options if preferred over the other. More importantly, it doesn't really explain if the 2 options are equivalent or there are edge cases where the 2 options are not equivalent if we use "add" after "mixed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that you can often mimic `git reset --soft` with `git reset --mixed` and `git add`.

However, I can imagine edge cases where it is not possible. Assume you edited a file, then added your changes to the index with `git add`, but after that you realized that it was wrong and you went back to the previous version using some editor. Now, you are in a situation where you think the file was not changed at all, but your changes still sit in the index. Here comes the difference: `git reset --soft` will keep your staged changes while with `git reset --mixed` they will be lost forever (`git add` will not help you, because you have nothing to add).

Those flags have different use cases: `--mixed` is often used to remove changes from the index which were added to it by an accident, and I have a feeling that `--soft` is used very rarely. I have used `--soft` flag only once, when I forgot to create a feature branch and made a commit on master.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Exactly the case I was looking for and also a great example that helps to better understand how the index interacts with git add and commit. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Consider what `git reset` (in its three modes, soft vs mixed vs hard, and not its other additional things that aren't one of these three modes at all) does.  You run:

```
git reset --<mode> <commit-specifier>
```

and it does the following three things, or maybe 2, or 1:

1. (`--soft`, `--mixed`, `--hard`) It changes the *current branch name*, as stored in `HEAD`, to point to the given commit.  With `--soft`, it now stops.
2. (`--mixed` and `--hard`) It replaces the existing index contents with the contents of the *commit* you selected in step 1.  With `--mixed` (or the default), it now stops.
3. (`--hard` only) It replaces the work-tree contents with the files as updated in step 2.

Now, you *can*, if you choose, select the *current commit* as the target in step 1, by running `git reset HEAD` for instance.  If you do this, the updated current commit in step 1 is the current commit.  That is, step 1 makes no actual change.

If you run `git reset --soft HEAD`, step 1 makes no change, and `git reset` then quits.  So this does absolutely nothing.

If you run `git reset` without `--soft`, however—with no argument at all, which defaults to `--mixed`, or with `--hard`—it goes on to step 2: replace the index's contents with the files that are frozen for all time into the current commit.  In effect, this un-does any `git add` that you did earlier.

If your goal is to re-do all the `git add` again afterward, this isn't useful.  But if your goal is to *not* re-do all these `git add`s, it can be.  Consider, for instance, this example—not terribly useful by itself, but meant to be illustrative:

```
git checkout somebranch
<edit for a while, test, `git add .`>

# think: wait, I don't want to commit everything
git reset      # index now matches HEAD

<edit README file to announce that the NEXT commit changes a lot of things>
git add README
git commit     # make a commit in which everything is the same except README

git add .
git commit     # make final commit in which everything is changed
```

To make sense out of all of this, remember that there are, at all times, *three* copies of each file:

- There is a read-only, frozen-for-all-time copy of each file (`README.md`, `main.py`, etc., whatever files you have) in the *current commit*.  You can change which commit is the *current commit* any time you like, using `git checkout` or `git reset`, but the commit itself is frozen for all time: none of its files will ever change at all, nor will its commit message, author, and so on.
- There is a frozen-*format* copy of the file in Git's index.<sup>1</sup>  You can change this all you like: you can overwrite the copy of the file with a copy of another file or another version of the same file.  You can even *remove* the file from the index entirely, using `git rm`.  The index copy is in the frozen format, ready to go into a commit, but is not itself a commit, so it *can* be changed.
- Last, there's a usable version of the file.  It's not in some special Git-only format, and the *rest* of your computer programs can actually *use* this version of the file.  That version resides in your *work-tree*.

It's very typical for the index copy of a file to match at least one other copy—the `HEAD` copy, the work-tree copy, or both—but in fact, you can have all three files be different.  To do that, just:

- edit the work-tree copy (be sure to save it so that `git add` can see it);
- use `git add` to copy the work-tree copy to the index; and
- edit the work-tree copy some more (and be sure to save again).

Now the file is both *staged for commit*, meaning that the `HEAD` and index copies differ, and *not staged for commit*, meaning that the index and work-tree copies differ.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, what's in the index is just a mode, file name, and *reference* to an internal Git *blob object*.  The blob object represents the frozen-format copy of the file's *content*.  Reset (`git reset`) copies the mode, name, and hash ID into the index.  Adding (`git add`) compresses (makes ready-for-freezing) the work-tree file by making a new blob object, or finding the already-existing blob object, that will re-expand to the work-tree file later.