# How do I safely merge to a remote branch on Github

Tags: git, github, git-merge, feature-branch

For work I had to clone a repository. On my local repo I made some changes on the master branch. But now I need to make those same changes on a new feature branch in the remote repo. How do I do that without changing the master branch of the origin repo. I'm following [this tutorial](https://devconnected.com/how-to-push-git-branch-to-remote/) which says that I have to pull from origin but I'm afraid my changes will overwrite the master branch of the origin. Maybe what I should have done was to create a local feature branch instead of modifying code on the master branch?

Comment: Regret Type 3? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/341994

Answer (score 1):

Create a new local branch

```
git checkout -b myFeatureBranch
```

Then set an upstream for it and push it to the server

```
git push --set-upstream origin myFeatureBranch
```

Comment: And then maybe add: git branch -d master