# How to combine multiple commits into one?

Tags: git, github

How do I squash multiple commits into one? I'm working on a fix for an issue on a open open source project and I did the following so far:

- I forked the repo on GH
- cloned the fork onto my machine
- checked out a branch, added the upstream repo (the repo that I forked), made changes to the code, `git add`, `git commit`, `git push -u origin my_branch` .
- logged onto GitHub and made the pull request.
- After that, I made multiple changes to my pull request via GitHub.com and committed each one.

One of the mods now whats me to combine all these commits into one, but I have no idea how. I also need to make some more changes to the code. But this time, I want to make the changes locally (instead of doing it on GitHub). So, how can I update my local repo so that it reflects that changes I made on GitHub?

Thank you!

Comment: Google `git-merge squash` Or read `man git-merge`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the fork belongs entirely to you. So first say `git pull` locally to sync the fork down to your local machine. Then, still working locally, use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/341994) (regret type 1) to squash all the commits on your branch into a single commit: `git reset --soft` down to the commit where you started the branch, and immediately `git commit`. Finally, `git push` to sync back up the fork. The pull request will be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Explained everything perfectly.

Comment: You might have to say `git push -f` in the last step, because the remote repo doesn't like when you "rewrite history". But the fork belongs to you, so there is no problem with forcing it to obey.