# How to squash upcoming commit into the previous commit?

Tags: git

First of all on `zsh` I am using [git-auto-fetch plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch). This may messes up if it is automatically take place right after squash is done and led me end up in the `rebase`.

I just want to update my previous commit with the new one. I believe squashing is solution for this, where commit and squash it with the previous commit; hence latest commit is updated with the new one.

If the latest commit is:

```
* b5d2f27 Update Contract
```

Basically, if my latest commit is `b5d2f27`, and I've modified some files locally. I just want to include those changes in commit `b5d2f27`.

---

I have followed: [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/2402577) as but it usually ends up in `rebase`.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git add -A .
git commit --quiet --no-verify --edit \
   -m "$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
git push -f
```

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. The phrase "update my previous commit with the new one" is meaningless, and the phrase "Basically I want to remove b5d2f27 and push my commit" leaves one asking: _what_ commit do you want to push, if you just removed it? Do you mean _replace_ the previous commit with the new one?

Comment: Do you mean you made commit A and then commit B and you want to push commit B but _not_ commit A? If so, do you mean you want to push commit B with none of the _effects_ of commit A? Because if you do, that is not what a squash does; a squash just _combines_ the effects of A and B into a single commit C.

Comment: Or do you mean you made commit A and have not made commit B but you want to erase commit A and now make commit B instead? What? Maybe you could draw us a diagram of what the goal is here.

Comment: I want to combine my new commit (that is going to be pushed) with the previous commit as a single commit ; I want to commit B with the affects of commit A. @matt

Comment: Okay! So that is [Regret Type 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/341994). Reset soft back to before the previous commit, and now just commit. Done.

Comment: I have done the `git reset --soft HEAD~1` like on my script code; but it keeps the previous commit too and sometimes it ends up in `rebase`

Comment: Yep, because you did not reset back far enough. Look at the example in the link! If you have `A-B-C` and you want to combine B and C, you need to reset soft back to A.

Comment: Ah I was doing if its `A-B-C` and my new commit should be `D` but I was doing the `git reset --soft HEAD~1` operation before commiting `D`

Comment: What do you mean " sometimes it ends up in rebase "?

Comment: Please see : https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b022cfdd6634dedf91a1986e0054e72e  ; after the commit using `git reset --soft HEAD~1` it builds up on top of the previous commit

Comment: have you tried `git rebase -i 1f457a4 `, and then changing `pick` to `fixup`?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean by ` changing pick to fixup` // I was using `git log --graph --decorate --oneline \$(git rev-list -g --all)` I think its graph guide me wrongly

Comment: I think I found it real problem: `zsh` was doing auto fetching if there is a change in the directory using ( `https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch`) which leads to mess up if its completed before `git push -f  ` of the squashed commits completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

and then, in the interactive window, change the second `pick` to `fixup`

---

Alternatively, if you haven't yet made a new commit but just want to include your latest changes in your previous commit, you can do

```
git commit --amend
```

Comment: What do you mean by `second pick to fixup`

Comment: When you do `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, you will get an interactive window. In that window, change the second `pick` to `fixup`

Comment: It says: `error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.` along with following github sitatus: `@de1245be rebase-i !4 ?2`

Comment: Just to clarify - your latest commit is `1f457a4 `, and you've modified some files locally (but not staged them). You'd like to include those changes in commit `1f457a4 `. Right? If so, you can just stage them (`git add`) and the amend your last commit (`git commit --amend`)

Comment: Yes exactly! Like I just want to push my new local changes into the latest (which is the previous commit)

Comment: After `git commit --amend` should I do `git push -f ` ? because it remains as `master ⇡1 ⇣1 !1` right after the commit // even after the push my latest changes is not included into the previous commit

Comment: If you had already pushed your previous commit and want to overwrite it, then yes, you will have to do `git push -f`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
git rebase --interactive [commit-hash]
```

**[commit-hash]** - is the hash of the commit just before the first one you want to rewrite from.You can read the whole thing as:

*Merge all my commits on top of commit **[commit-hash]***.

[Source](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git)

Comment: Same as existing answer.