# Bitbucket - Single commit for all the commit's

Tags: bitbucket, commit, git-branch, git-amend

I am currently using `BitBucket` as version control for my project. I see different `node (In the image with black dots/multiple commits)` of `Branch graph` on multiple commits. How can I make sure only `one node` is present on branch graph for all commit I make? In other words all `commits` must be seen as `1 commit` and `not incremental`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fpD5.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fpD5.png)

I have tried using `git commit --amend -m "Message"` but it always gives me

`error: failed to push some refs  hint:'git pull' before pushing again`

So I `git pull` and `push` again which creates a new commit.

Comment: It _sounds_ like maybe you are just saying you want to squash multiple commits into a single commit, to clean up your history. That's very easy with an interactive rebase.

Comment: @matt I have add the image, please check. The black dots(nodes) are commits. For each commit new commit, new node is generated. I am trying to get just single node for all commit on graph

Comment: @matt I hope question is now clear

Comment: Okay so for different commits different nodes are created, in my team they just want 1 node to be created for all commits. That's the reason I am using `append` so that no new commit is created and changes are pushed to previous commit. `Pushing to old commit without creating new commit is what I am trying to achieve`

Comment: If you are working on a branch and you make many commits, you can squash them down to one commit before you push and ask for a pull request. Maybe that’s what your team is telling you. Why not ask them whether that is what they mean?

Comment: Yes that is somewhat similar to what I am looking for. `Eg` If I have already made 1 commit, then my 2nd commit should not be as new commit but update on commit 1. `This looks like I just make 1 commit in the end`

Comment: No problem, just interactive rebase and squash them together. It’s easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking to do is perfectly reasonable; I like to do it too. I can just keep making commits on my branch, and then when I am ready to push, I *squash them all down to one commit*, and push. So the people seeing my PR see it as a single finished product; they don't need to see the whole history of how I got there.

One way to squash all commits in chain into a single commit is to do a *soft reset* back to the first commit and then amend that commit. See my [three types of regret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard/59675191#59675191); this is regret type 1.

However, on the whole I like to use *interactive rebase* for this. Here is an example. We are working on a branch `mybranch` and we have made three commits:

```
* cd591cc (HEAD -> mybranch) z
* cdbe774 y
* 3ce8eaa x
| * e86283a (master) b
|/  
* 4227e7d a
```

Now I want to push so we can merge to `master`. But I do not want three commits `x` and `y` and `z`. I want just one commit.

So I say:

```
git rebase -i 4227e7d
```

(because that is where the branch started). The editor opens and I see this:

```
pick 3ce8eaa x
pick cdbe774 y
pick cd591cc z
```

I rewrite it like this:

```
pick 3ce8eaa x
squash cdbe774 y
squash cd591cc z
```

I save and close the editor. The editor opens again so I can write my commit message. I delete everything in the editor and replace it with:

```
my very cool work
```

I save and close the editor. Now things look like this:

```
* bb8c9fb (HEAD -> mybranch) my very cool work
| * e86283a (master) b
|/  
* 4227e7d a
```

Just what I wanted! My branch is just one commit, and now I am ready to merge (or push for a pull request).

Comment: You _can_ do this with doing a `commit --amend` every time you commit, but I can never remember to do that, and I don't like it; it is too limiting. With interactive rebase, I can just keep working, go forward, go back, change my mind, try things, and when I'm all done and ready to push, I clean up by squashing it all into one commit as I showed you.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, I will try this out

Comment: Hey @matt What should I do after `save and close the editor`? Do I need to do `git push` after this?  On `git status` it says `your branch has diverged and have 1 and 6 different commits each, respectively(use "git pull " to merger the remote in yours)`

Comment: I still have push changes `to the open pr` to merge into `master branch`

Comment: Well it’s very hard to rewrite history you’ve already pushed but you might just be able to push with force. But next time don’t do that! However that’s a different matter really.

Comment: Ohh, I am confused, so what should I do next?

Comment: I think you should ask this as a new question! Personally I would withdraw the PR and delete the remote branch and start over.