# Create Branch and move commits from Main to Branch

Tags: git, github-pages

I have my 'Main' repository with 8 commits

```
Main 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8
```

I would like to create a BranchA and move commits 6, 7, 8 on it:

```
Main 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
BranchA                \ 6 - 7 - 8
```

To then continue in main:

```
Main 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 9 - 10 - 11
BranchA                \ 6 - 7 - 8
```

Is there a command to do this directly?

If not, which is the best sequence to obtain it?

Comment: I don't think it can be done directly, but, with `HEAD` on `main`, you can run `git branch BranchA` and `git reset HEAD~3`.

Comment: That is the right answer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/341994, this is Regret Type 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to understand here is that branches in Git are not *things*. They aren’t places, or collections of commits, or histories. They are just *names*. A branch is a name that is currently attached to some commit; and it is movable, so it can be attached to some other commit, as desired. To "make a branch" just creates a name and points it — by default to where we are right now.

And `HEAD` is an even simpler name; it just points (usually) at the branch name where you are working.

So, as already explained in a comment: you have

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 <- main <- HEAD
```

So `main` is pointing at 8, and we are *at* 8. So now say `git branch branchA`. Now you have

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 <- main <- HEAD, branchA
```

with both branch names pointing to 8. Note that you are *still on `main`;* you didn't checkout `branchA` so `HEAD` still points to `main`.

Since `branchA` now looks exactly the way you want it to, you can now just move `main` by saying `git reset --hard HEAD~3`. That simply lifts the `main` pointer and moves it, and so it gives:

```
                  main <- HEAD
                    |
                    v
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 <- branchA
```

But that is topologically identical to what you want:

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 <- main <- HEAD
                     \
                      -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 <- branchA
```

You are *still* on `main` so just keep working: add-and-commit, add-and-commit.

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 9 -- 10 <- main <- HEAD
                     \
                      -- 6 -- 7 -- 8 <- branchA
```

Meanwhile `branchA` is sitting there holding your old place at 8.

Comment: Ok Thank you it worked perfectly.
At the end of preocess I had the problem to synchronize with Github (it was not possible a normal push) and I used: 
> git push --force