# Revert committed files into working memory

Tags: git, github

I committed multiple files, and now when i type: `git status`: I got message: (use "git push" to publish your local commits).

How can I return those files into working memory?

My goal is to return all files into working memory, and not lose any changes which I committed?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `working memory`. There is [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) for restoring files into previous state.

Comment: I wanted files which I committed previously to return into my vs code like before commit. With all changes which I already created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard)

Comment: It seems like your phrase "working memory" is what Git means by its phrase "working tree".

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:  **git reset --mixed HEAD~1**

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know that when you initial a git repository in your local machine it has three different areas as follow: 
1-Working Area 
2-Staging Area (Index) 
3-Repository (local)
when you use `git add {file name(s) or patterns or .}` you send files from the working area to the staging area and when you create a `git commit` in fact you send the files from the staging area into the repository.
here is some useful command to use: 
-Removing files:
`git rm {file name}`  #Removes from the working directory and staging area
`git rm --cached {file name}` #Removes from staging area only
-Renaming or moving files:
`git mv {source file name} {destination file name}`
-Viewing the staged/unstaged changes:
`git diff` #Shows unstaged changes
`git diff --staged` #Shows staged changes
`git diff --cached` #Same as the above
-Viewing the history:
`git log` #Full history
`git log --oneline` #Summary
`git log --reverse` #Lists the commits from the oldest to the newest
-Viewing a commit:
`git show {commit id}` #Shows the given commit
`git show HEAD` #Shows the last commit
`git show HEAD~2` #Two steps before the last commit
`git show HEAD:{file name}` #Shows the version of file.js stored in the last commit
-Unstaging files (undoing git add)
`git restore --staged {file name}` #Copies the last version of file.js from repo to index
-Discarding local changes:
`git restore {file name}` # Copies file.js from index to working directory
`git restore {file name(s)}` #Restores multiple files in working directory
`git restore .` #Discards all local changes (except untracked files)
`git clean -fd` #Removes all untracked files 
***your answer:*** 
To restoring an earlier version of a file
`git restore --source=HEAD~1 {file name}`

Answer (score 0):

`git reset` is probably what you are looking for.

The reset command has several options:

- `--hard` discard any changes
- `--soft` keeps changes on your staging area
- `--mixed` keep some changes on staging area and some in working directory

There are even more parameters. Refer to [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for details.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not bring files into my working memory

Comment: I needed concrete example, but I found it. Thanks :)