# Create a branch from another branch with its latest changes?

Tags: git

I need to create a branch from another branch with its latest changes. I use bitbucket, I created via website panel and I checked out to the new branch in my VS code but I realized that the latest changes don't come. (suppose there is a branch called `A` which created from the `development` branch and the `A` branch has a bunch of commits and now I need branch `B` from `A` with its commits) and it seems I create my new branch B from the A but without commits. how can I bring changes in branch B?

Comment: Incoherent. A branch doesn't have "commits". A branch is the name of _one_ commit. All other commits either are or are not _reachable_ from that one commit (by way of the parent chain). Now pose your question in the light of those facts. What's the problem?

Comment: @matt in the A branch I did several changes and I did several commit for that changes. today I create new branch from A. I need those changes to come to B. obvious

Comment: If you create B from A, the commits you created while on A _are_  "on" B. Again I ask, in terms of what Git really is, what's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are having Regret Type 3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard

Comment: @matt Problem is the commits I created while on A are NOT "on" B.

Comment: Yes they are. If you `git log B` you will see them listed. Therefore they are "on" B in the only meaningful sense.

Comment: If you are on A (`git switch A`) and you create B (`git switch -c B`), then all the commits "on" A are now also "on" B. That's just a fact. If you have a supposed counterfact, then you are not doing what I just said. But you have not shown what you _are_ doing; you are just waving your hands. Show what you have done and what is not satisfactory about what `git log B` tells you.

Comment: Have you made the commits locally, not pushed them, and then created the branch in the BitBucket web UI from an old state of your branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command in branch `A`:

```
git checkout -b B A
```

This way you have branch `B` with all `A` commit.