# Documentation of Default Target of "git merge --squash"

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

Sometimes I squash a bunch of commits together. Usually my commands follow this pattern:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
git merge --squash HEAD@{1}
git commit
```

Today, though, at step 2, I got distracted by something (squirrel? Slack? Facebook?) and I forgot to end the `git merge --squash` command with `HEAD@{1}`. Yet it magically did what I wanted.

I can't find any documentation that omitting the target of the merge will default to `HEAD@{1}`, but it was nice that it worked out.

Is there documentation on this somewhere?

I see the following from `git help merge`, but it doesn't seem to answer the question:

```
--squash, --no-squash
           Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit). This
           allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

           With --no-squash perform the merge and commit the result. This option can be used to override --squash.

           With --squash, --commit is not allowed, and will fail.
```

Comment: Side note: `git reset --soft HEAD~4; git commit` will do it, you're just changing ancestry of your current checkout.

Comment: I agree with jthill; see my essay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard/59675191#59675191

Comment: Thank you! `--soft` it is for me from now on. my mind is blown. I was a little leery of asking this question as I thought there must be a clear answer somewhere else, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: i guess the difference is that `git merge --squash` creates a nice commit message about what you included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
git merge
```

(with no options and no arguments) "means":

```
git merge @{upstream}
```

Adding options, such as `--squash`, does not change this, so:

```
git merge --squash
```

is a synonym for:

```
git merge --squash @{upstream}
```

The `@{upstream}` syntax means *locate the commit pointed-to by the upstream of the current branch*.  The upstream of `master` is pretty typically `origin/master`.  The upstream of `dev` is pretty typically `origin/dev`.  This pattern repeats.  The actual upstream can be found with `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
```

which for instance in my Git clone of the Git repository for Git produces:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

i.e., I'm on `master` and its upstream is `origin/master`.  (This particular clone is primarily a reference clone for me, so I just keep its master in sync with the other various duplicates of the Git repository for Git.  `@{u}` is a shorter way to write `@{upstream}`: less mnemonic, but easier to type in.)  Whatever commit `@{u}` meant, that's the one that Git squash-merged with.

As [jthill noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962338/documentation-of-default-target-of-git-merge-squash#comment125447567_70962338), you should consider `git reset --soft` for your particular goal.  The soft reset moves the current branch, without touching the index and working tree, which avoids doing the work that `git merge --squash` would have to perform.  The resulting index-and-work-tree will be the same either way, and since `--squash` does not create `.git/MERGE_HEAD` (and does imply `--no-commit`) the final `git commit` will behave the same way as well.

Comment: Cool, thanks! `--soft` for the win. my mind is blown. I was a little leery of asking this question as I thought there must be a clear answer somewhere else, but I couldn't find it. And I also learned that you can hyperlink comments in stackoverflow! Double win.