# How to delete last pushed commit

Tags: git, github

I would like to know how to delete a last pushed commit without affecting my local unstaged changes?
This is the last commit id: ae04c55ce4b43c90c4bd8de9e4152b561b5055d6

Comment: I think if I do reset --hard then my local uncommitted changes will also go

Comment: P.S. Google helps a lot solving this problem ;-)

Comment: I already did answered your question about `--hard` flag in the previous one you asked. I will share the same [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard) once again, this time, please read it before posting new question.

Answer (score 0):

To revert remote changes, you will need to `push force` (which I recommend to fully understand before proceeding)

Then steps in will be

- Remove locally: `git reset --hard HEAD~1`,
- Then remove remotely `git push --force origin <branch>`

Again, the force flag is dangerous, an alternative will be to use the `revert` command to eliminate changes with an additional commit.

Comment: I used this and all of my uncommited changes were also got deleted

Comment: In the question is part `without affecting my local unstaged changes`
`git reset --hard HEAD~1` will remove unstaged changes.
 You need to use `git reset --soft`