# How to cherry-pick a merge commit + the commits that were merged?

Tags: git

If I have a branch that looks like:

```
M --- Merge Branch 'foobar' (sha ABC)
    o did stuff (sha DEF)
    o did other stuff (sha GHI)
```

and I cherry-pick the merge commit:

`git cherry-pick -m1 ABC`

Then I will have ABC, DEF, GHI all in one commit...  I would like to actually just have the same structure from the other branch, and have the merge + the individual commits separate..  How can I do that?

Comment: Cherry pick the actual commits and then merge

Comment: I don't understand the diagram. Which way is time supposed to run here? What's the earliest of the three commits? And in what sense is it true that "Then I will have ABC, DEF, GHI all in one commit"? That seems a false premise.

Comment: @matt I made a branch, I did GHI, and then DEF, then switched to master and did `git merge my-branch --no-ff` ...  So now I have another branch I am on, and I want to pull all of that off of master, so it looks exactly as it does on master.

Comment: So why not cherry pick GHI, and then cherry pick DEF, and then cherry pick the merge commit? Actually what I would do is make a temporary branch and rebase, but it's exactly the same really, because rebase _is_ cherry pick.

Comment: But cherry pick copies; perhaps "pull all of that off of master" means, not copy, but you wish those commits had never been on master to start with? Then just make a branch and reset master hard. That would be Regret Type 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard

Comment: @matt because I have a million commits and am looking for a way to do this easily.  I tried cherry-picking with a range `git cherry-pick DEF^..GHI` (though this example is bad because I actually have like >20 commits, not 2) but it was having conflicts which I could not understand why, so I aborted..

Comment: Well that's why I said I would rebase. But conflicts are normal and you need to learn to deal with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several ways to reach similar goals :

- using `rebase` :

```bash
# start with a temp branch at commit DEF :
git checkout -b temp DEF

git rebase targetbranch
# or, if the fork point between 'foobar' and 'targetbranch' is not
# at GHI, instruct rebase to only take commits starting from GHI :
git rebase --onto targetbranch GHI^

git checkout targetbranch
git merge --no-ff temp
git branch -d temp
```

- using `cherry-pick` :

```
# create a temp branch from your current tip :
git checkout -b temp

# list all commits to pick:
git cherry-pick GHI DEF

# merge temp branch into targetbranch:
git checkout targetbranch
git merge --no-ff temp
git branch -d temp
```

- using `cherry-pick` (take 2):

```
# create a temp branch from your current tip :
git checkout -b temp

# the range of commits to pick should be :
# the range "first parent of M" .. "second parent of M"
git cherry-pick M^..M^2

# merge temp branch into targetbranch:
git checkout targetbranch
git merge --no-ff temp
git branch -d temp
```