# Merge select files in git repo with local repo which don't have any commits

Tags: git, dotfiles, git-worktree

I have a remote git repo with more than 100 commits. I have a copy of those files locally and have some changes. I initialized a git repo locally. I added the remote as `origin`, but now I am facing some problems. The local repo is only initialized, and no commits yet, and no files staged. I have some important changes locally which are not present in the remote. The problems:

1. I can't pull remote because that will overwrite the existing local files
2. I can't commit all local changes and push because they don't share the same commit history
3. I can't force push also, because that will delete the commit history in remote

What I am trying to achieve is to pull all commit history from remote, and then merge the local commit into the latest commit on remote.

Please note (in case this info will also help): This is a dotfiles git repo. In my previous machine, I set the local git repo using the command `git --work-tree=/home/user --git-dir=.git/ init`. In my new machine, before setting this repo again, and pulling the changes, I instead copied the config files and other dotfiles from my old machine and made a few changes. Now in the new machine I used the same command but the above mentioned problems were raised. Both remotely and locally I have the `~/.mozilla/firefox` also backed up, so it contains binary (or similar) files which are neither readable nor writable, but have been changed while using firefox, including `.db` files. So for those files, I just wanna keep the local ones, and ignore the remote ones.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I can't pull remote because that will overwrite the existing local files

Right.  So don't do that.

> 2. I can't commit all local changes and push because they don't share the same commit history

You never commit *changes* in the first place.  This statement starts with an incorrect assumption!  That's where we'll fix things.

> 3. I can't force push also, because that will delete the commit history in remote

This part is right, so we won't do that.

Now, before we go about fixing #2 above, let's get into this part:

> Both remotely and locally I have the `~/.mozilla/firefox` also backed up, so it contains binary (or similar) files which are neither readable nor writable, but have been changed while using firefox, including `.db` files. So for those files, I just wanna keep the local ones, and ignore the remote ones.

This is ... difficult, and also illustrative: it shows the difference between a *backup system* (which should save and restore these databases) and a *version control system* (which should not).  Git is a version control system, not a backup system; as such, you really don't want to store these databases in it.  But you already did, so you're stuck with that.  **There is no good Git solution to this issue.**  Consider redoing everything so that these databases are excluded from your version control.  (Whether you want to include or exclude browser bookmarks is a separate question, but note that these are typically imported and exported as XML or modified HTML or some such, and Git's merge algorithms perform poorly with these file formats.)

With that caveat—that these version-controlled databases are going to be a problem and there is very little you can do about it—let's go on to items 1 and 2 above.  **You have been led astray by learning the `git pull` command.**  It's not inherently *bad*, but `git pull` is composed of two more-basic commands:

- `git fetch`, which you *do* need to use; followed by
- a second Git command (usually `git merge` by default), which you *must not use* here.

Knowing that `git pull` = `git fetch` + second Git command, and what each of these two commands do, would have gotten you a lot closer to your answer.  All you need to do is:

1. run `git fetch` to obtain all the *commits* from the remote named `origin` (i.e., run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`).
2. Set things up so that you are "on" the desired branch, with the desired branch-tip as the current commit.
3. Add and commit your files.  You will get a full snapshot of every file you added—and *only* those files—in the same way that every commit holds a full snapshot of every file.  The parent of the *new* commit you just made will be the commit you were "on" when you ran `git commit`, so the *difference between* the parent of the new commit, and the new commit itself, will be the differences between the files in each of those two commits.

(In other words, that's where "changes" come from.  Git does not store changes.  Git *stores* snapshots.  But the snapshot-diff duality [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40617288/1256452) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646342/git-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs-then-why-is-rebase-necessary-to-remove-old/73653427?noredirect=1#comment130064838_73653427) means we can *work with* changes whenever we like.

Step 2 is the hard part.  The "normal" way to "get on a branch" is to use `git switch` (or, for Git versions predating 2.23, `git checkout`), but this asks Git to overwrite your working tree files.  As these files are not (yet) in any commit(s), **you definitely do not want to do this**.  You:

- are in a repository that has no commits until you run `git fetch`;
- are on an *unborn* or *orphan* branch;
- have *no branches* (see above bullet point);
- have an *empty index* unless you have already run `git add`;
- have a *non-empty working tree* with various dot-files.

I've reproduced this condition:

```
$ mkdir tt && cd tt && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git remote add origin ../t
```

(The `../t` bare repository here is a repository full of dinky test files and other random stuff from old stackoverflow answers.)

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch
$
```

So, no branches, no commits; let's run `git fetch` and populate with commits:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 125, done.
...
 * [new branch]      branch     -> origin/branch
 * [new branch]      fix-signal -> origin/fix-signal
 * [new branch]      foobranch  -> origin/foobranch
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         tag-foo    -> tag-foo
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Note that while I'm still on my own `master` branch, my `master` branch *does not exist*.  I can change the name of this unborn branch with `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` or, if my Git is new enough, `git branch -m` (move, i.e., rename, branch).  It's up to you what branch name you want to use here.  For illustration I'll switch mine to `main`.  Then I will *create it based on the upstream `master`*, which I now have in my `tt` repository as `origin/master`:

```
$ git switch -c main
Switched to a new branch 'main'
$ git branch main origin/master
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    a.py
        deleted:    ast_ex.py
        deleted:    bar
        deleted:    clob.c
        deleted:    closure.py
...
$ git rev-parse HEAD
11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d
```

Note how it now looks as though I've *deleted* every file.  This is because the *index* (aka *staging area*) remains empty.  I have to `git add` files to populate it, **or** run commands such as `git restore -S` to copy files *from* the current or `HEAD` commit into Git's index, or both.

The current commit is now `11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d`.  That's the commit I specified when I ran `git branch main` to create the name `main`.  I did that by writing `origin/master`, but note:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d
```

There's that same hash ID: `origin/master` *means* `commit 11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d`.  Branch names like `main` and remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are just *ways we have Git remember hash IDs for us*.

If I want, I can now run `git reset`, which does a `--mixed` reset, which means it moves the current branch name to the commit I specify.  I'll use the default, which is `HEAD`, which is the current commit specified by the name `main` which now holds the same commit hash ID as `origin/master` which is the commit I'd like to "append to" after all.  (That's the commit I chose with `git branch main origin/master`!)  Then, having "moved" the current branch `main` from `11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d` to `11ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d`—i.e., not having moved at all—`git reset --mixed` will *read into Git's index* all of the files from the commit I moved *to*.  So now no files will be *staged* for deletion.  Instead, the index / staging-area now matches the *current commit*, and `git status` reports on the difference between the index and my working tree (mine is *empty*, yours won't be):

```
$ git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       .gitignore
D       a.py
...
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    a.py
...
```

(the `git status` list is the same as the `git reset` list here, and again consists of every file in Git's index, which is now every file in the current or `HEAD` commit).

If I didn't want to fill Git's index like this, I can `git rm -r --cached .` or (a bit of a special case hack) `git read-tree --empty` now.  But in general this is what you want to do:

- You want to *populate the Git objects database with commits*, using `git fetch`.
- You want to *set up the correct orphan/unborn branch name* if necessary.
- You want to *create the branch name* at the correct commit (as found by `origin/whatever`), so that your *next* commit will use *this* commit as its parent.
- Then you want to build a new commit as usual.

You can, if you like, set up your new branch as a *different* branch—not `main` or `master` or whatever—and you can set it up without an *upstream* using `git branch --no-track newbr origin/master` for instance, or you can remove the upstream later with `git branch --unset-upstream`.  You can `git restore -S` (but *not* `-W`) and `git reset --mixed` (but *not* `--hard`) if you like.  These are all just fiddling around the edges: the *fundamentals* you want are those in the bullet points above this paragraph.

#### On a completely different note: dotfiles repositories

I like the idea of storing (some / many / most of) my "dot-files" in a repository.  What I don't like is having a `.git` repository in my home directory, where those dot-files live.  So what I did was write an overly fancy program: I put my committed dot-files into a repository and then have the *program* install them into place, mostly with symlinks wherever that works.  This lets me pick and choose which dot files actually get saved and hence work around problems like the Firefox binary databases.

Mine is messy and highly imperfect and I have not fussed with it for a few years at this point.  It's probably not a great starting point for anyone else.  But I think the general idea is sound enough: don't store *the* dot-files in a Git repository, store *prototype* dot-files that get copied or symlinked or whatever.  Maintain the prototypes, not the actual files, so that you can accommodate quirks as needed.  In other words, [add a level of indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288623/1256452).

Comment: I am having a little bit of hard time understanding all of it, but I will try to re read and understand and try it myself, thanks a lot tho for the detailed answer. And about the dotfiles, yes I don’t as well like having the `.git` in my home dir and so what I do is make a `dotfiles` git repo inside my home dir with the work tree as the home dir, and add a bunch of `.gitignore` files inside multiple dirs which ignore everything (`/*`) and then exclude the ignores using `!` for the specific things that I want to be tracked/version controlled.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Although I said I will read your answer again I didn't, but today one idea popped in my mind. What I did was first backed up the local changes in a git directory. And then on the main branch I pulled down the remote by hard resetting, meaning only the remote changes will persist and all local changes will be removed. Now I went to the backup and restored all files, meaning all the previous local changes will return. Now in the main branch I added all and committed and pushed, this seems to make it work. Thanks for your help and I will look for a better way to store `.mozilla/`