# Rebase two commits from master in a new feature-branch

Tags: git, rebase

I accidentally made two commits on my master branch and now I want to rebase them both onto a new branch.

Here you can see the initial situation...

```
-- -- -- C1 C2 (master)
       \
        (new-feature-branch)
```

...and how it should look in the end:

```
-- -- -- (master)
       \
         C1 C2 (new-feature-branch)
```

Thanks for youre help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard Regret Type 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the pointers around

```
git branch temp new-feature-branch # create a temp pointer where master is
git checkout new-feature-branch
git reset --hard master # set feature where master is
git branch -f master temp # set master where new-feature-branch was
git branch -D temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your history looks like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
-- -- (new-feature-branch) -- C1 C2 (master)
```

In that case, fast-forward merge the feature branch, then re-create master:

```
git checkout new-feature-branch
git merge --ff-only master
git branch -f master HEAD~2 # set back 2 commits (adapt if it needs to be moved back by more commits)
```