# Git reset does not remove new files or add old ones

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij and working on a git project where I'm facing the following problem :

Let's imagine I have an empty git project. And then I do the following operations :

- Create new file called : NewFile.txt
- Add and commit (commit id : 1XXXX)
- Create new file called : MistakeFile.txt
- Add and commit (commit id : 2XXXX)

Now at this point I realise that I shouldn't have added the MistakeFile.
So I do :

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

However on my IDE the MistakeFile is still present, while it doesn't exist in the commit I just reseted to.
FYI: In this case I haven't pushed anything to the remote repository yet. All commits are local ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you want to reset in hard mode.

```
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```

By default, git resets in mixed mode, this means it only affects the history of the branch but not the files in the working area.

While in hard mode it affects both.