# Git combine all commits between two commits using their hashes

Tags: git

Given this git branch,

`-- c1 ---- c2 ------ HEAD`

I want to combine `c1` and `c2` and everything in between into one commit.

Requirements:

- I know `c1` and `c2` hashes, but not their relative positions to `HEAD`.
- I want to do this programmatically (call it in a script), so I cannot use interactive mode.

I know this question has been asked several times, but I cannot find any existing answer that satisfies those requirements.

Comment: can you explain in more details your constraint "I want to do this programmatically" ?

Comment: e.g: is there some strong constraint to have this action run in an unsupervised context (a CI runner ...) ? is there some reason why you would have to apply the same rewriting action several times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it (call the branch you are on `originalBranch`):

```
git switch --det c2
git switch -c temp
git reset --soft c1
git commit -msquash  
git rebase --onto temp c2 originalBranch
git branch -D temp
```

The idea is this:

- We get ourselves back at `c2` and plant a branch name `temp` there, so that we can find it again.
- We then squash from `c2` all the way back to `c1` inclusive — that's the soft reset followed by a commit; this is a [type 1 regret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/341994). The name `temp` now points to this new single squash commit.
- Finally, we return to whatever was the original HEAD (which I have named `originalBranch`) and move all the commits starting at (but not including) the old `c2` onto the new single squash commit, which (as I have already said) is pointed to by the name `temp`.
- Our work is now done, but we no longer need the branch name `temp` for anything, so we delete it.

So we have now gone from this:

```
A -- B -- C1 -- ? -- ? -- C2 -- D -- E -- F <- originalBranch
```

To this:

```
A -- B -- C1 -- squash -- D' -- E' -- F' <- originalBranch
            \
             -- ? -- ? -- C2 -- D -- E -- F
```

The old commits, as you can see from my diagram, still exist, but they will all be mopped up during the next garbage collection because no name points to them any longer.

Comment: Please don't provide magic scripts that leave beginners scratching their heads and without clue what is going on. Could you please explain the idea behind the script?

Comment: Why do I get merge conflict error?

Comment: @FelixFourcolor : matt's script should work *if there is no merge commit between `c2` and `HEAD`*. Do you have merge commits ? check `git log --oneline --graph HEAD`, or `git log --merges --oneline c2..HEAD` (<- will only display merge commits, if no output then no merge commits)

Comment: @LeGEC There are. What do I do then?

Comment: Resolve the conflicts and resume the rebase. But unfortunately you can't do that in a script. You could try adding `--rebase-merges` to the rebase command...

Comment: "I know `c1` and `c2` hashes, but not their relative positions to `HEAD`." If `c2` precedes `c1`, then this script will do some time travel.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me because of merge conflicts, and I trust @LeGEC that it's impossible to resolve them in a script. But since this is the best we have, I'll accept this answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tool that does this out of the box, but it can be scripted.

Pseudo code:

- checkout `c1^`
- do a squash-merge of `c2` and commit the results
- cherry pick `c2..HEAD` onto the results

Potential problem:

- if there were any merge commits between `c1^` and `HEAD`, cherry picking `c2..HEAD` will create a mess.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code? I'm not familiar enough with git.

Comment: matt did a great job of it