# Does git reset --soft HEAD do nothing?

Tags: git

And I mean in comparison with `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. I'm probably wrong about something here, but let me explain my doubt. I understand that `git reset HEAD` (without the tilde) will simply discard the staged changes, not actually deleting any commit, since we're not specifying here that we want HEAD to move ~1 or ~2 commits.

I also read in here that the --soft option is meant to keep the files staged, while the mixed option would uncommit and unstage them, but leaving them in the working tree; finally, --hard would delete them even from the working tree, lefting I guess only the untracked files. So yeah, sorry for the long post, but what does `git reset --soft HEAD` do?

This is in a context where you have staged the files but not commited them yet. Say I'm trying to discard the staged but uncommited changes but I don't want to delete any commit, since I didn't commit these files yet, thus deleting something would actually delete a previous commit that has nothing to do with this case.

UPDATE: I checked on git and yeah it seems to do nothing in this case!

Comment: Using `--soft` keeps the changes made in the commit (adding them to the index, i.e. staged for commt) and moves the branch. Whereas `--hard` will not keep the changes made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard)

Comment: But is git reset --soft head the same as git reset --soft head~1? I thought the last actually deleted a commit and the first only removed the staged file, but preserving the last commit, since there's no new commit yet (in a context where files are staged but not commited yet).

Comment: No `head` and `head~1` refer two different things. The answer given below is a good description of what is going on

Comment: If you just need to discard staged changes, `git restore` with `--staged` flag is what you need instead of reset

Answer (score 2):

In git, there are "three states" to keep track of:

1. state of the files on disk in working directory
2. HEAD ref, i.e. the "current branch"/"current commit" git is pointed at
3. state of git's staging area, what's indexed/tracked or not

For `git reset --soft HEAD`:

1. resets HEAD to point to the ref, HEAD, i.e. changing nothing
2. `--soft` will not change the index nor working tree

Therefore, it does nothing