# stop visual studio code push

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I made a `commit` in visual studio code then `push`, but I accidentally missed that a 1GB file was commited. I saw this mistake and moved the file to a `.gitignore` path and `push`ed that commit, but **now it is stuck syncing this huge commit** and I have no idea how to stop it, and I couldn't find information online, any suggestions?

PS: I downloaded the plugin GitLens to try to fix the issue, right-clicking and reverting commit from gitlens didn't fix it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: @colin thank you I will look now

Comment: it successfully states it's removed, however it is still attempting to sync

Comment: Did you try closing it and re-opening?

Comment: @colin I did even after the removal hoping it would fix it, any other ideas?

Comment: I dunno, I'd need to see your setup to know more I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reset twice and lose my local changes, then copy them over again, I used this post: [Remove a git commit which has not pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611215/remove-a-git-commit-which-has-not-pushed)