# Remove specific commit in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, azure, github, visual-studio-2022, commit

In my .NET Core project using Visual Studio 2022, I have some pushed commits I want to remove specific commit from commit history without effect the commits pushed after this commit - is this possible?

I don't know if there a way except to do reverse the commits

Comment: Have you seen [On undoing, fixing, or removing commits in git](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a git commit which has not been pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611215/remove-a-git-commit-which-has-not-been-pushed)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not provide such functionality; you need to use the git command  line.

See the comments for a couple of references on how to do history rewrites.