# Remove Historic Git Commit so It Does Not Appear in "git log -p"

Tags: git

There is some sensitive information that was committed to a repository about a month ago that I'd like to completely remove any trace of.

I'm adept at using `git rebase` and know I can use this to change the commit, and answers like [How to delete a 'git commit' from LOG, like it had never existed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901542/how-to-delete-a-git-commit-from-log-like-it-had-never-existed) show how to just delete a commit using `git rebase`.

However, the pre-rebased hash of the offending commit is still findable using

```
git log -p $BAD_SHA
```

So, even though the commit no longer appears under `git log`, with the above command someone can still see the sensitive information even though it has been "deleted" using rebase.

Is there a way to essentially completely remove a SHA after it has been rebased, so that it no longer shows up using `git log -p $BAD_SHA`?

---

Addendum: I have tried `git gc --prune=all --aggressive` after rebasing, and this does not solve the problem.  There is no branch either on the local or remote repository that still references the bad hash I want to get rid of.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the reflog?

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

Answer (score 1):

If the commit is not viewable on any existing branch, garbage collection should take care of it.

```
git gc --prune=all
```

Comment: I've tried `git gc --prune=all` and `git gc --prune=all --aggressive`, but the offending SHA still appears in `git log -p $BAD_SHA`.  There is only one branch in this entire repository, both on local and on remote.

Comment: See if this finds any references to it: `git describe --all --contains $BAD_SHA`

Comment: The reflogs also point to commits, so that might have prevented gc from cleaning it up as well.

Comment: Tags also point to commits, so again, unless the tag is deleted, their pointed to commits will hang around as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after performing garbage collection with `git gc --prune=all --aggressive`, I also needed to completely remove the repository locally and then re-clone it.  Now the offending commit does not show up in `git log -p $BAD_SHA`.

Comment: This should have been done by garbage collection.  Maybe it wasn't eligible yet.