# Remove Commit from Repository History

Tags: git, github, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete a ‘git commit’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-to-delete-a-git-commit)

Knowing that this will change history, I want to remove some accidentally commits from the history of a repository. I would like all other commits to retain their states of the repository. So the changes of commits I want to delete would be covered each by the commit after them.

How can I do that in Git and how can I apply that also or only to the repository on Github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, "squashing" is what you want.

```
  -A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H
```

Given the history above, you should pick the commit before the first commit you want to squash. Let's say you want to squash F and E into D and H into G, so the commit before the first one is C.

```
  git rebase -i C
```

You will be presented an editor with a text file containing something like the following:

```
pick D
pick E
pick F
pick G
pick H
```

Modify this into:

```
pick D
squash E
squash F
pick G
squash H
```

You will be asked to review the commit messages of the new commits,

The resulting history will look like:

```
  -A-B-C-D'-G'
```

**Please note** You're always squashing newer commits into older ones, not vice versa. Therefore `pick G` and `squash H`. Think of it as amending a commit after your history moved on.

PS: To get this into your GitHub repository, you'll have to to a forced push `git push -f origin` (given that `origin` is your GitHub remote).

PPS: For further information see the [man page of git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: Then my history will become `A-B-C-D-G`?

Comment: It's `-A-B-C-D'-G'`, I edited my answer. But `D'=D+E+F` and `G'=G+H`.

Comment: Are later commits affected? For example if I start with `A-B-C-D` and just squash `C` into `B`. Will the result be `A-B'-D` or `A-B'-D'`?

Comment: The latter. Rebasing will always rewrite the whole history after the first changed commit, even if you only change the commit message.

Comment: This is sad but I understand that. And isn't there a way to squash a commit into the *next* one? That makes a difference to me since the author of these two commits differ.

Comment: Effectively you can, but git-rebase walks your history from old to new. So the old commit is first and the new one is squashed into it. The patches of both commits are combined and you're able to select which commit message to use (or even write a new one). So the result makes no differences which commit is squashed into which other commit.