# How to remove a commit?

Tags: git

I merged some commits in Git and now I need to delete this commit as it has some confidential information. I need to put the HEAD in the commit before the merge.

Comment: Do you tried to take a look at https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data ?

Comment: I used git reset --HARD HEAD~1     but it reset the commit to the previous one not delete it. I need it to be deleted

Comment: Ah, you only needed to restore the previous HEAD. Ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a 'git commit'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-to-delete-a-git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `git rebase` for this job, because a nice list pops up where I can choose the commits to get rid of. Choose how many commits you want to list, then invoke like this

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Sample list

```
pick aa28ba7 Sanity check for RtmpSrv port
pick c26c541 RtmpSrv version option
pick 58d6909 Better URL decoding support
```

Then git will remove commits for any line that you remove.

Comment: I did it and a git- rebase to do poped out.. now how can I choose the commits?

Comment: Thanks .. it helps.. but the commits are not completely deleted. They are still saved and anyone can reset the branch to that commit. Is it possible to delete it compeletely?

Comment: Git will automatically garbage-collect "dangling" commits (that are not part of any branches or tags) after a certain number of days. You can run garbage collection manually with [`git gc`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are another way to do this, but I have a solution in this case.

Let's suppose you are using `master` branch.

First I checkout the commit I want to be the last in master and recreate the master branch.

```
git checkout 2fa59698256c4c3fb85c6e32741071797d5965b3
git checkout -b master
```

Then I pull back forcing the server to remove it history.

```
git checkout --amend
git push origin master --force
```

This will erase all commits after.

You can use `git rebalse~x` then do the push with force... But When I'm in trouble I always remember to use the checkout, that I do all the time to switch between branch's.