# remove commits (forever) from git history

Tags: git, github, revision-history

I would like to permanently remove specified commits from the entire history of a git repository.  I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git), in which the following is recommended:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
git push origin HEAD --force
```

That's fine and resets the status of my repository, but in no way does it remove my commits.  I would like to literally roll back history and discard changes to the repo since  4 revisions ago.

Could anyone help me with this?
When I try the above and look at the revision history in Github, I still see unwanted commits sitting there.

I saw [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data), but I wanted to check whether or not there were other options before investigating this solution.

Comment: You write: *in no way does it remove my commits*. The commits you're trying to get rid of may be part of other references' ancestry.

Comment: I should have been clear - I'm only dealing with the master branch, and no other author was involved in the commits.

Comment: Ok, but in what sense does that command *in no way remove [your] commits*? Can you still see them in the output of `git log`? In your remote repo? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I see them on Github

Comment: Have you tried (be sure that's what you want, though) `git push --force origin master`?

Comment: PERFECT - please post this as an answer for me - this is precisely what I needed.

Comment: This does the exact same thing as the command you posted...

Comment: @remram Only if `HEAD` is indeed pointing at `master`.

Comment: If it is not pointing at master, then the previous reset is very wrong and you lost data on another branch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, what actually happens when you run

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

is unclear, but I can think of at least two reasons why it may fail to force-push `master` to `origin`:

1. the currently checked out branch is *not* `master` and is a branch already up-to-date on `origin`, or
2. you have a detached `HEAD`.

Make sure `master` is indeed the currently checked-ou branch, by running `git checkout master`; then run your force push command. Alternatively, specify `master` explicitly in the `git push` command:

```
git push --force origin master
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the unwanted commits are not referenced anymore by a branch or a tag (i.e. called "loose objects"), then they will be automatically removed by the garbage collector. By default, the GC acts on objects older than 90 days.

You can still manually trigger an earlier GC with:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=all
```

However, that will act only on your local repository, not on GitHub. GitHub runs a weekly GC with its own options so if you want to remove the commits **now**, then you will have to delete the repository, recreate it and push your local after GC cleanup.