# git prevent files from being cloned

Tags: git

Hi normally I use eclipse with egit to do the git magic, but I accidentally added a whole folder to git where files reside I don't want to be under version control.

Is there a possibility to remove them in a way that they don't show up when the repo is cloned to another machine?

I tried git rm and commited/pushed the changes, but it is still cloned to a 3 machine.

Regards and thanks

Comment: Have you already pushed additional changes on top of the faulty commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
git rm -r --cached <target_folder> # Removes folder from git but retaining the local
git commit -m "<target_message>"
git push origin master
```