# Squash older commits while preserving SHA1s of newer commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a commit history like this:

```
f85179d ten
7de4071 nine
5c7a482 eight
9585035 seven
b41bffc six
d102f05 five
5a28cb9 four
6fc27c9 three
524b0c7 two
bb7e6ae one
```

I would like to squash commits "one" to "five" into a single commit such that it looks like this:

```
f85179d ten
7de4071 nine
5c7a482 eight
9585035 seven
b41bffc six
4tg56y5 Squash five commits into one commit.
```

Importantly, I want to keep the SHA values the same for the unsquashed commits. That means I cannot just use `git rebase --root -i", because it will change all the hashes.

Comment: Btw, hex values only have letters a-f, not t, g or y. 

Comment: Ha! Fun. Of course! I have created a new form of hex! @Evi1M4chine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to rewrite the history of your git repository *and* maintain the commit ids of existing commits.  A commit id is generated from the content of a given commit (including the contents of the directory tree, the author, committer, date, etc) *as well as* the id of its parent.  This means that if you change any commit in your history, every subsequent commit is going to have a new commit id.

For more details about the format of git repositories, see [this doc](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html), or [this one](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: The key point for me is, "as *well* as the id of its parent."

Comment: And this is an intentional design to prevent tampering with the history.