# Delete all commits prior to the current one in a pull request

Tags: github, git-commit, pull-request

I have a pull request going on, which contains several unneeded commits by me.

The current commit is the only one, I want to keep.
The commits have already been pushed to github so I can't use git rebase.

How can I delete all commits prior to my current commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: the problem is, that the commits are already pushed to the repo