# GitLab cancel or delete a push

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

I want to cancel my last push, because a pushed the app/build folder changes Is it possible to revert a push or the last push in Gitlab?

Comment: Thanks for your constructif answer.

Comment: Do a hard reset to the previous commit....?

Comment: Yes, I tried I hard reset and I pushed it on GitLab, and it works Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Either you can [delete the commit locally and use force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338744/390177) or create a revert commit via GitLab UI (GitLab 8.5 or newer):

Select your commit in the history you want to revert and click on the revert button:

[image]

There will be a modal dialog. You can choice if you want to create a Merge Request or directly commit it to the default branch:

[image]

[More details](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/revert_changes.html#reverting-a-commit)

Comment: Thanks a lot CSchulz, but I am on the 8.0.5 version, I suppose i can't see the revert option.

Comment: But I found an other way, by a hard rest.

Comment: In this case you have done the same as described in the linked answer.

Comment: By this way the wrong commit remains in the history. Is there any way to erase it as it never happened?