# Git: how to delete repeated commits that appear on another branch?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have a situation where my branches look like this:

```
*   d3b91f2 (HEAD, origin/narrowdown_lblrtmprogram, narrowdown_lblrtmprogram, lowercase_main_src_code) resolve gi
t-pull conflict.  gitignore *.mod and *.so
|\  
| * 0ed828f number all the markers which a typical run goes past
| * 7a9fd6a gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
| * 40e824a stop tracking lblrtm/lblrtm_v12.2_linux_intel_dbl
| * cfb6866 stop tracking some previously tracked files but are now in .gitignore
| * 314451c lay down markers in main program
| * a0d6edf gitignore *.mod
| * 5e9352a gitignore `runs/` directory
* | 2e48384 number all the markers which a typical run goes past
* | a0db0ed gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
* | df52ddc stop tracking some previously tracked files but are now in .gitignore
* | 37fc6d1 lay down markers in main program
* | 9deee6a gitignore *.mod
* | 9ae357a (origin/trace_lblrtm_lw_flux_calc, trace_lblrtm_lw_flux_calc) gitignore runs/
* | 4ce55a0 gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
* | 3691140 stop tracking lblrtm/lblrtm_v12.2_linux_intel_dbl
|/  
| * 3c8edd0 (origin/master, master) gitignore runs/
| * 969a8e1 gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
|/  
* 11ed99d Revert "Add write() statements to mark path through lblrtm source code for example solar run"
```

There appears to be two branches that are merged at the topmost commit `d3b91f2`.  However, commits from `3691140` to `2e48384` are effectively the same as those from `5e9352a` to `0ed828f`.  Is there a way to get rid of those redundant commits from `5e9352a` to `0ed828f`?  Because looking at

```
[jk@nuwaln01 aerlbl_v12.2_package]$ git log -10 narrowdown_lblrtmprogram --oneline
d3b91f2 resolve git-pull conflict.  gitignore *.mod and *.so
2e48384 number all the markers which a typical run goes past
a0db0ed gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
df52ddc stop tracking some previously tracked files but are now in .gitignore
37fc6d1 lay down markers in main program
9deee6a gitignore *.mod
9ae357a gitignore runs/
4ce55a0 gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
3691140 stop tracking lblrtm/lblrtm_v12.2_linux_intel_dbl
0ed828f number all the markers which a typical run goes past
```

and

```
[jk@nuwaln01 aerlbl_v12.2_package]$ git log -10 --oneline lowercase_main_src_code
d3b91f2 resolve git-pull conflict.  gitignore *.mod and *.so
2e48384 number all the markers which a typical run goes past
a0db0ed gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
df52ddc stop tracking some previously tracked files but are now in .gitignore
37fc6d1 lay down markers in main program
9deee6a gitignore *.mod
9ae357a gitignore runs/
4ce55a0 gitignore *.o and lblrtm executables
3691140 stop tracking lblrtm/lblrtm_v12.2_linux_intel_dbl
0ed828f number all the markers which a typical run goes past
```

these commits do not seem to belong to either branch `narrowdown_lblrtmprogram` or branch `lowercase_main_src_code`, so I cannot use `git branch -d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interactive rebase might be helpful.

```
git rebase -i 11ed99d
```

and flag commits you want to delete with `d` marker.

Just make sure to have a backup branch or you will have to do a `git reflog` if something fails.

Comment: Thanks, this works!  Though I later realised that the repeated commits are actually on the same branch, taking into account of which my question should become "how to delete a range of commits in the commit history", which has already been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git.