# Resetting a few commits via git

Tags: git

I recently made some unnecessary changes to my existing code and accidentally deleted my controller (Using rails). At this point I was on my master branch since I just had to make a small change. Hence I had committed the changes to my repository.

To revert this, I use git reset --hard HEAD to get back to my old code. What I want to do now is remove the 2 commits ahead of this version and want to start working only on the head I just moved to. How do I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your commits by `push force` on HEAD.

```
git push origin HEAD -f
```

Comment: Glad it helps you :)

Comment: Rather than `-f` (or equivalent `--force`), I recommend using `--force-with-lease` so that you don't accidentally overwrite any commits that someone else may have pushed since you last fetched.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. As per me, the best way is as below:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

It will open a rebase-to-do list file. Remove the commits you want to delete. Then save and close the file.

Comment: This also works fine. I just figured it out. I'd use this for a kind of situation where I'd want to remove a patch in between versions. But push force on HEAD seemed to do what I required just fine. Thank you :)