# Delete Github Commits

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-commit

Im trying to host my personal website on Github. I was logged in as different user on Gitbash and pushed the code. In that repository I could see contributors as 2 and few commits which I would like to remove. Can I delete unwanted commits. Making this repository completely clean would be fine but I want to make number of commits zero.

Comment: Do you want to reset the repo to a previous state before they committed? Do you want to keep their changes or delete those?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git

Comment: I want to delete those changes

Comment: git push origin HEAD --force
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.