# How to delete a commit in Git that is already pushed to a remote branch and present in my coworkers local repos?

Tags: git, version-control

How to delete a commit in Git that is already pushed to a remote branch and present in my coworkers local repos?

The first part is relatively easy (deleting a commit locally and from the remote is already well described on stack overflow, for example: [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git))

But the problem arises when that faulty commit (or a set of commits) has been already downloaded by other coworkers. When they execute `git pull` command, the removed commit will still appear in their local history so that the commit can be restored...how to avoid it?

Is there a sort of `git pull --force` command that will disregard local commits that have been deleted from remote?

Comment: Once history has been made publically available, it is essentially inviolate - there is no good way to do what you want. What you _should_ do instead is revert the commits in question using `git revert <sha>`, which will generate _new_ commits that exactly undo the ones you don't want.

Comment: Try reverting back to and commit the new version and push. A git pull from your co-worker should solve

Comment: I read about `git revert <sha>` command but my goal is to erase that commit from the history

Answer (score 1):

Forced fetch (`git fetch -f`) or pull (`git pull origin +master`) are dangerous because they discard local commits that haven't been pushed yet. So your course is:

1. You remove the offending commit with `git rebase -i` and force-push the branch: `git push origin +master` (let's talk about `origin` remote repo and `master` branch).
2. All your coworkers do:

2a. `git branch save-master master` to create a new branch that points to old master — i.e. the unpushed commits.

2b. Forced pull: `git pull origin +master`.

2c. Cherry-pick unpushed commits from the old master: `git cherry-pick save-master` (adapt the command to the number of unpushed commits).

2d. Remove old master: `git branch -D save-master`.

Answer (score 0):

**`git pull origin master --rebase` can update your coworkers repos and make their changes on the top of updated `master` branch** (assume it’s master branch here).

Since you have already know how to delete a commit which has pushed to remote repo (`git reset` or `git rebase -i`), I will only illustrate the second part by graphs: update your coworkers local repos with updated `master` branch.

Assume the `master` branch original history is:

```
A---B---C---D---E   master
```

And you find the commit `D` is a wrong commit and you delete in commit history:

```
A---B---C---E'   master
```

While your coworkers still work based on the old `master` branch with their local changes:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---G   master
```

After they execute `git pull origin master --rebase`, their local commit history will look like:

```
A---B---C---E'---F'---G'   master
```