# Restore local and remote project to a previous commit in git

Tags: git, github, netbeans, version-control, netbeans-8

I modified files in my working directory. But I've made mistakes and I would restore a previous commit , not the last but one specific commit with its SHA.  I already committed and pushed the changes on the remote server (github).  How could I do? Is it right following command?:

```
git reset --hard specificSHA
```

It seems work when later I push on the remote server I have a conflict. I want the old version of the project in local and in remote server, I don't mind lost recent modify.

Actually I'm working on Netbeans. How can I proceed in Netbeans too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+pushed+commit