# How to remove specific revision in history for specific page on wiki

Tags: github

I have some documentation on GitHub repo wiki. This wiki, as expected, contains several pages. Each page has its own revision history. For the sake of some cleanup, I would like to remove some specific revision from the history of one page.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Each page has its own revision history.

This isn't exactly true. GitHub wikis are Git repositories, and the revision history of your wiki all lives in a single repository. Each commit probably only touches a single page, though, since that's how the online editor works.

You could [clone your wiki](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages/#cloning-wikis-to-your-computer), [rewrite its history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to remove the offending commit (e.g. [with `git rebase -i`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1338756/354577)), and then `--force-with-lease` push it back to GitHub.

However, that's a pretty drastic thing to do simply to remove a commit from your wiki's history. Does the revision really offend you that much? It should be invisible to users unless they're deliberately reviewing your wiki's history.

> For the sake of some cleanup, I would like to remove some specific revision from the history of one page.

My recommendation is to just leave it where it is.