# Git - How to undo commit in wrong local branch?

Tags: git

My Git setup is such that I work in a local "feature" branch and commit changes to this branch as I work. When the code is ready I merge into my local "develop" branch. I then push the changes in my local "develop" branch to the remote "develop" branch.

I made some changes to a file and committed them without realizing I was on my local "develop" branch rather than my "feature" branch. I realized my mistake before I pushed the "develop" branch to the remote "develop" branch, so the changes remain local.

How do I undo this commit to my local "develop" branch? I am using Tortoise Git but I can still use the Git command line if needed.

Note: This is not my first commit to the feature branch or first merge to the develop branch.

Comment: Is this the last commit in "develop", or have you made other commits to "develop" since?

Comment: @melpomene - This was the last commit to the local develop branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` will eradicate the last commit in your branch (and any local changes you may have made). Use with care. `git rebase -i` can be used to delete commits from the middle of your history. Use with care.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways you could resolve the problem.  One way would be to `cherry-pick` the commit on your `feature` branch.  Then `reset` your `develop` branch to the previous commit.

1. `git checkout feature`
2. `git cherry-pick <commit hash>`
3. `git checkout develop`
4. `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

Comment: Note that 1. and 2. are only necessary if you have an existing `feature` branch that already has some commits.

Answer (score 4):

If you forgot to create a branch for your feature, you should create one:

```
git branch feature
```

Then you can reset `develop` back to where it should be:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

If you already have a `feature` branch where you want to move the commit that you accidentally made on `develop`, then you can use `git cherry-pick`:

```
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick develop
```

Then you can reset `develop` as above. Just be sure to check it out first:

```
git checkout develop
```

Answer (score 0):

So, let's talk about how to move those commits over to the feature branch and then undo them.  For the purposes of this explanation, we will assume that only errant commits have gone onto your `develop` branch locally.

1. Get the commit hashes for each of the errant commits on `develop`.  You can do this in your gui, or checkout `develop` and run `git log` in a terminal.  Copy paste them someplace you can reference them later.
2. Checkout your `feature` branch.  You will now run a `git cherry-pick <commit_hash>` for each of the commit hashes you saved in step #1.  You want to do this in the order in which they were committed onto the `develop` branch.  This replays each of these commits onto your local `feature` branch.
3. Do a hard reset on your `develop` branch to get it back to the remote version.  Assuming that the remote reference is `origin/develop`, you would do `git reset --hard origin/develop`

Note there are other means of doing this, using `git rebase` or using interactive rebases.  This is just the easiest way I could think of to convey it for someone who has an unknown amount of git experience.

Note that if you are worried about being able to revert in case things don't go as expected, you can leverage `git tag` to make rescue tags.

Comment: If there are several "errant commits", you can use `git rebase` instead of multiple `git cherry-pick`s.

Comment: Yep, certainly-- there are faster, more clever ways, for sure-- cherry-picking is more manual, but I figured it was a "safer" approach in case this was a relative git beginner.

Comment: Note that my comment is more for the OP and future visitors than for you as the answerer. I assume that since you answer questions in [tag:git] there is a high likelihood that you are familiar with rebase.