# How to remove certain commits from a PR?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I uncommitted some commits that I pushed to a PR by doing a `git reset --hard feature/DCMP-959`.

Then I made some small changes and committed it with the correct message, but when I pushed it to the PR, it repushed the uncommitted commits I previously removed:

[image]

How do I completely eliminate commit `388be463463` and commit `6b3a92b79bb` from my PR and leave the latest one?

I need to eliminate these commits because I am getting this error message:

> JQL Check Unable to merge this PR because one or more referenced JIRA
>   issues are not: a) Relevant to this project; b) An allowable issue
>   type; c) In an allowable status; or d) Assigned a fix version and/or
>   parent fix version

and my build failed.

Comment: Are you looking to do a rebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git this question looks like it will point you in the right direction

Comment: What made you think the reset *"uncommitted some commits"*? Have you tried actually rewriting the history? Note you'll have to force push if you do so.

Comment: If your commits have sensitive information then it's worth fixing it. If it's only code bombs which you have fixed in the later commits I suggest leave it. It's just my personal opinion. To fix you have to reset to the commit before 388be463463 and then cherry pick or manually merge the commit you want

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly, I tried that SO post, but found it became unmanageable for me.

Comment: @karthick, I don't mind leaving it, but the merge failed with this error: `JQL Check
Unable to merge this PR because one or more referenced JIRA issues are not: a) Relevant to this project; b) An allowable issue type; c) In an allowable status; or d) Assigned a fix version and/or parent fix version`. Is there a better way to resolve this error? Quite frankly, I never worked with Bitbucket before so I don't really understand it, but thought cleaning up all these commits that are essentially the same would help. The last commit is essentially a variation of the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make 1 commit out of your changes in branch `feature/DCMP-959` and merge it let's say into `master`, then:

```
git checkout feature/DCMP-959
git merge origin/master
# keep all the files as they are in working dir, but remove all commits
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m 'Nice looking message'
# will re-write the commits in your remote branch
git push -f origin HEAD:refs/heads/feature/DCMP-959
```

If you want to remove (squash) only some of the commits, then you need to use `git rebase -i` or cherry-pick/squash manually each commit.

Comment: Stanislav, `master` is not used at all. The master branch would be `release/2.0`. So with that said, are you saying do a `git merge origin/release/2.0`? `feature/DCMP-959` was branched off `release/2.0` for me to make the changes and then create a PR to merge them back with the new branch changes, makes sense?

Comment: Whatever branch you intend to merge into

Comment: Stanislav, I am getting `✗ git merge origin/release/2.0
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: You need to resolve all merge conflicts and `git add` those files that had conflicts. Those conflicts were probably unresolved from your previous merge.

Comment: Stanislav, everytime I resolve the merge conflicts and git add and commit and push, the build fails again and when I try to revert, I get the same conflicts again. What is going on?

Comment: So in your remote branch you have only 1 commit that's different compared to your release branch? The error message above says that DCMP-959 task either doesn't exist, or is not in progress or something else. So I guess you'll need to change something about the task in JIRA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196169/discussion-between-daniel-and-stanislav-bashkyrtsev).