# In git how do I delete/drop a specific commit from history (rebase) programmatially?

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-rebase

I know how to *interactively* modify a git history and `drop` a specific commit but I didn't find a way to do that fully automatically.

I'd like to identify specific commits (e.g. containing a magic string) and have them deleted by a script.

Something like this:

```
# identify and remove all commits which would be merged to master but should not
for i in $(git --no-pager log --grep='no-push' --pretty=format:"%h" --no-merges HEAD ^master)
do
    echo "Drop commit $i"
    git rebase --drop $i   # <== this is what I want to do
done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318688/3001761?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32318688/1668622) (thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)):

```
# identify and remove all commits which would be merged to master but should not
for i in $(git --no-pager log --grep='no-push' --pretty=format:"%h" --no-merges HEAD ^master)
do
    echo "Drop commit $i"
    git rebase -p --onto $i^ $i
done
```

Comment: totally right and useful - in this case I know I get only git shas without any whitespaces. but feel free to improve the code