# Github Site shows deleted commit in the commit tab

Tags: github, git-commit, git-reset

I am new to github commands and I am a bit confused about what I am doing.

[image: what github shows me I currently have]

I want to delete the "MegaMan Game" commit, revert all changes, and make it dissapear from github 
history. Following this other stack overflow question [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git), I ran the `git reset --hard HEAD ~1` command. The commit seems to be deleted judging by the `git log` command, but on the github website it still shows that the "MegaMan Game" commit is still there. Also in source tree happens the same thing. The commit still shows there.
I am a bit confused. Is the website wrong about the commits? Did I run the command wrong?

Here is an image with the exact commands and what git

[image]

This is a noob question. I need help to undestand how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted commit in your local branch. You must send this change to the upstream branch(to github).

```
git push --force
```

Comment: I know I should not say thank you in comment but, thank you very much, it is now clear to me.