# How to delete commits from remote repo in GitHub with git?

Tags: git, github

How can I delete a commit which I already pushed to the remote? I got an answer to delete my latest commit. In the answers of this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git) someone said to do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to delete the latest commit. I did that and it worked but now when I push to the remote, it gives me this error

```
To github.com:an4s911/login-system.git                                                                                   
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)                                                                 
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:an4s911/login-system.git'                                                 
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind                                             
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.                                                         
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.                                                                              
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

it says to pull before pushing, so I pulled. But now I have the deleted commit back. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Tried a force push? The answer you linked to says that too

Comment: Oh, it worked! Thank You :)

Comment: What about deleting any commit in my log? I tried a lot of different things but nothing works perfectly. I used `git rebase -i <commit_hash>` but that doesn't seem to work. How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score -2):

**Solved!**

I forced the push to the remote by using `--force` are the `push` statement like this

```
git push --force
```