# ./.git-rewrite files after unfinished git filter-branch attempt

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

i have 2 local (say A and B) and one remote repository. unfortunately i added a huge folder into A and pushed it. as i wanted to pull it into a third local repository C (my laptop), it was not feasible any more. then i wanted to undo the adding of the huge folder in A and tried a `git filter-branch`' command which terminated with error as the disc quota was exceeded. now, when i run `du -h` in A, it shows several `./.git-rewrite` files, even if i checkout a commit before the addition of the huge file.

now - is there any way to undo the `git filter-branch` command? (my suspicion is that there is some alteration in the git history and i don't want to risk any damage) because then i would use [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git) to get rid of the folder and force the remote to forget it, too. as B is several commits behind, i would only use it as last option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use for the reflog!

running `git reflog` will provide you with a list of amendments to your repository, something like the following:

```
8730047 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: filter-branch: rewrite
30b6014 (refs/original/refs/heads/master) HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): test
(END)
```

This top item here is the filter-branch command I've just run in my own repository.
In order to undo it, I can run `git reset --hard HEAD@{0}` which will reset me back to my initial commit (titled `test`).