# File core is 131.63 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, coredump

Core- Program crash data.
I have no idea from where core file was generated. I deleted the file from my local, tried to push to the changes again to the remote, but still I am getting `File core is 131.63 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

i cleared the cache as well, still get no luck.  There is not occurrence of core file in my entire pc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com) as 131.63MB>100.00MB, which exceeds the [file size limit](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files) for git push, as indicated by GitHub official:

> If you attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will receive a warning from Git. The changes will still successfully push to your repository, but you can consider removing the commit to minimize performance impact.

> GitHub blocks pushes that exceed 100 MB.

You removed the file but the problem persists, *I think* it's probably because you committed the file before, but this push still contains the original commit. Try to [delete the old commit with the large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git).