# How can I get rid of wrong or duplicate commit in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

Sometimes I make an unneeded commit or a commit with a wrong message, how can I delete that commit in Xcode? I cannot find any delete option! How can I get rid of an unneeded commit, as shown below?

[image: List of commits, one is circled and says "wrong commit"]

Comment: Xcode's source control options are rather limited, but you can always use the `git` command line interface or another GUI of your choice (GitHub Desktop, Tower, etc). This question and set of answers details many options for deleting a commit and their implications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: @esqew: I am looking to see if I could use and try that link, jnpdx also gave that link before.

Comment: @ElTomato: As you see I am looking for delete