# Select commits from gitlab develop branch to create merge request to main

Tags: git, merge-request

I have develop and main branches on gitlab.
I want to create a merge request from develop to main includes a part of commits. Some of commits should be in merge request.
What should I do?

I tried git cherry pick but it take a lot of times

Comment: Is reverting the commits on top of your branch an option? Or do you want to have the commits available for later merging?

Answer (score 3):

`git cherry-pick` is the way to go if you only intend to include some of the commits from a branch... you need to set them apart and then cherry-pick should do it.... you might also consider creating a different branch using rebase interactive to select which commits to include.... say, something like:

```
git branch some-branch develop
git rebase -i master some-branch
# you will have an editor with a lot of commits that say _pick_
# keep that in the commits you want to include, delete the lines
# for the ones you don't want _or_ set them to `skip`
# save and continue
# and when rebase is done (you might get conflicts on the way)
# you will have your selection of commits so that you can
# create the PR
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep most commits on the dev branch, you could instead remove the commits you do not want.

I would suggest creating a new working branch to not lose any commits (as a copy of `develop`) and then removing all commits you do not want to merge from that branch.

You can remove commits by rebasing whatever comes after that commit on the commits parent, see [How do I delete a commit from a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1338728/10875738).