# Had to revert a commit but now need to push it back to remote repo

Tags: git

I had to revert to a previous commit by running:

```
 git revert <HASH>
```

So I go push the changes back into my remote repo and it failed with:

```
 ! [rejected]        ci_172 -> ci_172 (non-fast-forward)
 To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
 Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
```

Comment: Did you actually try to merge?

Comment: oh, gotta merge? sorry im new to Git and version control in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to force the push with `git push [remote-path] +[branch]`. So, if I was pushing master to origin, that would look like `git push origin +master`.

You can see more at [How can I remove a commit on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github).

Answer (score 0):

You need made a pull before

```
git pull origin
git push origin
```

The pull made a fetch and merge from origin. After this merge you can push your commit