# git revert HEAD when I have a local commit

Tags: git, git-revert

What happens if I execute the following command when I have a local commit (i.e. a commit that I haven't pushed to the remote repository yet) that I want to revert back ?

```
git revert HEAD
```

I researched a lot and found out that -

- "git revert $id" is used to revert back changes made in a particular commit commit ID - $id, and
- the HEAD itself is nothing but a reference to a commit ID (of the
  latest commit).

But I'm unable to understand that in this scenario (when I have a local commit), the HEAD would point at my latest local commit, or the latest commit on the remote repository ?

Why I ask this?

- I tried "git pull" from my branch, but it wouldn't happen as I had
  some changes in my local.
- So, I executed "git commit", and then tried the "git pull".
- Now,  "git pull" gave me errors (probably merge-conflicts : I
  happened to    missed out on the details of the "errors"), so I
  decided to revert my    commit, for which I executed "git revert
  HEAD".
- Now I'm confused that did this command (git revert HEAD) only revert my changes in
  the (local) commit I mentioned previously? or the last commit on the remote
  repository?

Comment: `HEAD` means the currently checked out commit (so it's definitely a local commit, and it _might_ be a remote commit too). `git revert <commit>` will create a "mirror commit" with every added and removed line switched. Since you tried to pull and got merge conflicts, you are probably amidst a merge and need to resolve/abort it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git reset command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).
Note that you will lose every changes (if any) in your current workspace.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358039/5037799) is useful to understand the differences between revert and reset.

Comment: Yes, I realized that's the best way I should have done it. But now, that I have already run "git revert HEAD", I'm in a mess. 
Is there any way to revert this command?
And just for knowledge sake, which commit do you think would have been reverted in the scenario I explained above?

Comment: @AkshitSingla, git reset --hard HEAD~1 will delete 1 commit. git revert made 1 commit. So you want to trash two commits, right ? Look at git log to be sure then trash the correct number of commits.

Comment: Sounds good! Just to confirm - hope this'll work even if I've pushed the changes, right ?