# I have 5 commits like 1 2 3 4 5
So if I revert 3rd commit what will happen 1 and 2 commits also revert back or still remain as is

Tags: git, github

I have 5 commits like 1 2 3 4 5
So if I revert 3rd commit what will happen 
1 and 2 commits also revert back or still remain as is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

Comment: *all* commits stay as they are. You get a 6th commit apllying the changes of commit 3 in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), git revert will 'revert the changes that the related patches introduce'.

Using your example, all the commits will stay the same (even, slightly confusingly, commit 3) but a sixth commit will be added that undoes the changes made in commit 3.