# Move an misplaced commit to a new branch

Tags: git, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

**Setup:**
I have commited a code change to local and also to remote, but in the wrong branch.

**My solution:**

1. Have checked out master and created a branch where the code change should be
2. Cherry-picked the commit from the wrong branch checkin and commited to new branch.
3. Check out the wrong branch. Reset to the first correct commit 
   and then force push it again to remove the faulty commit on remote
   branch.

**Question**: Is this the way to go? If I google it, I get that people use revert and I can't understand why as it seems more complicated and more dangerous.. Why should I use revert?

Comment: What do you call a "checkin"?

Comment: Change checkin to commit..

Comment: I've done revert, but using visual studio, worked for me my wrong commits were undid, not sure if this will work for you. Didn't use command line in that particular case, I relied on my ide for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `revert` some commit you create commit that negates target commit. Result as with `reset` but you do not have to `force push`, you can do simple `push` becouse you add to history not remove from it. Another difference you can `revert` commit that is not last in history. You can't use `reset` in this case becouse it leads to loosing all commits since target commit.

Also you may look this question: [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `3` I'd suggest *rebase onto*:

```
git rebase --onto COMMIT_BEFORE_WRONG WRONG_COMMIT branch_with_wrong_commit
git push --force-with-lease
```

This "cuts" the wrong commit.

When adding `-i` (for *interactive*) you can check that the right commits are moved.

---

Same result would come with:

git rebase -i COMMIT_BEFORE_WRONG

and then changing the word `pick` to `drop` in the first line of the "todo" file presented.

Answer (score 1):

> I [see] that people use revert and I can't understand why as it seems more complicated and more dangerous.. Why should I use revert?

*Should* is a strong word.  (Not quite as strong as *shall* or *must*, but at least fairly strong. :-) )

> ... Reset to the first correct commit and then force push it again to remove the faulty commit on remote branch

Whenever you have to use `git push --force` or equivalent, you are moving a branch name in a way that other people *might* not expect.  (*Might* is weaker than *should:* in a partial ordering, I would say *may < might < should < shall / must*.)  In particular, Git branch names naturally move in a progression in which commits get *added* to branches, because of the way that branches grow by making commits.

Consider:

```
$ git checkout <somebranch>
... work ...
$ git add <files>  # or --all or . or whatever
$ git commit
```

The `git checkout` step has the effect of attaching `HEAD` to a branch and copying that branch's *tip commit*, as pointed-to by the branch name, into your Git's index and work-tree so that you can work on it:

```
... <-F  <-G  <-H   <--branch (HEAD)
```

The branch named *`branch`*—the reference whose full name is `refs/heads/branch`—stores the raw hash ID of some commit `H`.  Commit `H` itself stores the raw hash ID of its parent commit `G`, which stores the raw hash ID of some commit `F`, and so on.  So we say that the name *points to* the tip commit `H`, which points to the earlier commit `G`, and so on.

The `git add` step updates your index / staging-area so that it is ready for the commit, and the `git commit` step creates a new commit.  The new commit stores, as its parent hash ID, the hash ID of the currently-checked-out commit `H`.  (It stores as its *snapshot* the frozen snapshot made from the current index / staging-area, of course.)  Then, as its final step, `git commit` writes the new commit's hash ID into the *branch name to which `HEAD` is attached:*

```
... <-F  <-G  <-H  <-I   <--branch (HEAD)
```

This is how branches grow, one commit at a time, when people make commits.  When you merge in a series of commits en-masse, either as a real merge or as a fast-forward not-really-a-merge-at-all operation, the branch acquires new commits as well, maybe many at once and maybe in a nonlinear fashion, but the important thing is that the new commits *always* lead back to the existing commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I---M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          J--K--L   <-- develop
```

Adding merge commit `M` to `master` leaves commits `H` and `I` *reachable* from `master`, because we can follow the backwards-pointing internal commit-to-commit arrows—rendered here as lines because arrows are just too hard to draw in text now—using the top-row arrow out of `M`.  (The left-and-down arrow from `M` to `L` allows us to ride from `M` to, say, `K` or `J` as well.  [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) has a nice analogy to the transit system in Portland, though any metropolitan train system is similar.)

But suppose we do this instead:

```
...--F--G--H--X  <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          J--K   <-- develop
```

and then realize that, oops, we meant to put commit `X` on `develop`.  We use any means appropriate to *copy* `X` to a new commit, such as cherry-pick or `git rebase --onto` (both do the same job).  Then we use `git checkout master; git reset --hard master~1` to push `X` out of the way, so that it's no longer on `master`:

```
             X
            /
...--F--G--H  <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          J--K--L   <-- develop
```

(Here `L` is the copy of `X`, put where we wanted it.)  This kind of branch-name-motion leaves commit `X` dangling without any way to find it—at least, no way in *our* repository.  But if we already use `git push` to send commit `X` somewhere else, some *other* Git has a name for it.  In fact, so do we:

```
             X   <-- origin/master
            /
...--F--G--H  <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          J--K--L   <-- develop
```

Our `origin/master`, which is our Git's way of remembering `master` on `origin`, still remembers that commit `X` exists.  That means that `origin`'s Git remembers `X` as being *on* their `master`.

That, in fact, is *why* we have to use `git push --force origin master`: to tell the Git at `origin` that it should *discard* its commit `X`.  If we do this before anyone else—anyone who has access to that Git—*also* copies `X` into *their* Git repository, we're fine: no one saw `X`, so no one can be harmed by our removing `X`.

The problems start to pile up if someone else *did* grab a copy off of the other Git.  Now there is some third Git repository that still has commit `X`, maybe in *their* `master`.  Maybe they have built new commits atop (their copy of) `X` that they *want to keep:*

```
...--F--G--H--X--Y--Z   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We're now going to tell them: *Oh, forget `X`, take it away from your repository too.*  That requires them to do their own `git rebase --onto` or similar, to copy their `Y` and `Z` to new commits that no longer lead back to `X`.

In short, by removing `X` from our Git and from `origin`'s Git, we put a burden on everyone else who *shares* these Git repositories: they, too, must all remove their `X`, and handle any consequences.

There are projects in which everyone agrees that this can happen—either at any time to any branch, or at any time to some specific subset(s) of branches.  In these projects, resetting branches and force-pushing is fine.  There are projects where there are no other users, or where you can force-push before anyone has a chance to pick up the mistake; in these cases, resetting and force-pushing is fine there too.  The problems occur when you start making a lot of work for people who are not prepared to do it.  In this case, making a *new* commit that simply *un-does* the work in `X` gives them a way to incorporate this new work in a way that they *are* prepared to accept.