# What is the equivalent of TFVC "Rollback" in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfvc

If I use **T**eam **F**oundation **S**ource **C**ontrol I can easily rollback to old changeset.

Assuming I have a file with 4 versions, each version have a changset:

- Changeset a126 - Version 1.
- Changeset b347 - Version 2.
- Changeset c560 - Version 3.
- Changeset d912 - Version 4.

Now I found a lot of bugs in Versions 3 & 4 and I want quickly return back to Version 2.

In Visual Studio I can click "View History" on the file, click on Changeset b347 ("Version 2") and then "Rollback".

Now I have a new changeset with the file in Version 2 and I can check-in it (I still have Version 3/4 in my history, so I can also return to them sometime).

In Git, I know there are `revert`, `reset` (hard, soft) but I don't know exactly what I need to do to reach the same result.

**So what is the best way to rollback to old version in Git (preferred via Visual Studio)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 commits `A-B-C-D`, the file `foo.txt` is changed in each of them, and the codes of `C` and `D` have bugs introduced by `foo.txt`.

1.Other files may be changed in C and D. If you want to rollback only `foo.txt` to the version of `B`:

```
git checkout B -- foo.txt
```

If you want to commit the rollback,

```
git commit
```

And the history will be `A-B-C-D-R1`.

2.If you want to rollback all the changes of C and D (including those of other files if any), and CD have been pushed to the remote repository:

```
git revert D C
```

And the history will be `A-B-C-D-R2-R3`.

3.If you want to rollback all the changes of C and D, and CD have NOT been pushed to the remote repository:

```
git reset B --hard
```

The history will be `A-B`. You could also use this solution for Case 2, but you then need to force-push the branch to overwrite the branch in the remote repository. If other contributors have fetched the old history, you need to tell them to fetch the new history.

Comment: Great answer! thank you! I don't think I can revert 2 commits in VS in one revert, but I can do it in Command Line :)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Here `git revert B..D` also works. `B..D` means `C` and `D`, and Git will revert them in the reverse sequence correctly. It's convenient when you want to revert a set of consecutive commits. Besides, the option `--no-edit` makes the process more smoothly if you don't want to edit the default revert message.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard b347
git push -f origin master
```

This removes `c560` and `d912` completely, but after that you need to force-push.

See [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset)

To undo changes creating new commits:

```
git revert d912 c560
```

Comment: But it will delete Version 3/4 commits and I don't want it. in TFVC the rollback not delete chengesets, but rather add a new changeset with Version 2.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted @ElpieKay answer because is more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what check-in is in TFVC, but if you just want to view the v2 file, you can `git checkout b347 -- thefilenameyouwant`

Comment: checkin = commit & push. I don't want only to view I want to view v2 file, them commit and push, to update my repo back to v2.

Comment: do you want the changes you made to v2 also to be in v3 and v4?

Comment: no. I want my repo return to v2 (but not delete v3 and v4 from commits history).

Comment: do you want the other files at v2 too or should they stay v4?

Comment: I want all files be back to v2

Answer (score 0):

To continue work on the v2 state of the repository in your working copy, you can do

```
# get uncommitted changes out of the way
git stash

# recreate v2 in the working copy
git checkout commit-hash-or-tag-of-v2 

# create new branch based on v2
git checkout -b branchname-for-new-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

### (1) How to roll back and "lose" Versions 3 & 4:

It's as simple as:

```
git reset --hard b347
```

**Explanation:**

- goes back to version 2.
- you will "lose" versions 3 and 4.
- if you still want to get versions 3 & 4 then those commits are still available in your reflog for a certain period of time depending on your settings (default time period is 90 days from memory).

### or (2) Create a new branch (to keep versions 3 & 4):

- You can simply create a new branch at version 2.

  `git checkout b347`

  `git checkout -b redo-work-from-version-2`

**Explanation:**

- You'll go back to b347, in a headless state. Just ignore this for the moment.
- We create a new branch called `redo-work-from-version-2`.
- Version 3 and version 4 will still exist and are available, but they will be on a different branch.